# Where did "too localized" go?

Tags: discussion, flags

I remember when [certain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273864/java-getting-a-trienode-instances-for-iterator-use) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091321/trie-iterator-hasnext-and-null-pointer) that were asked were flagged as **Too Localized**, meaning the poster was asking for something that was unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Has this been removed *in lieu* of something else?

The questions in particular are by the same user asking similar questions, seemingly about the same project. The first flag that came to mind without looking at the menu was "too localized", but alas it wasn't there.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to address this situation would be appreciated as well.

Comment: See [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) on the über-meta.

Comment: destroyed months ago

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, no wonder my search turned up nothing; it was on the other meta (of course). Thank you.

Comment: So `SO can use "Large blocks of code with requests for debugging without meaningful supporting info" as a specific OT reason.` refers to the *Unclear what you're asking* option, yeah?

Comment: It got axed because it is was used too often.  Not because it was ambiguous and most certainly not because it was less understandable than "this one was resolved".  Although questioners certainly favored pretending to not understand what it means, makes it easier to complain about it.  It was axed because the site was getting too many localized questions.  In effect solving the problem by lowering the standards.  It shows.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218061/238586

Comment: It's gone, and good riddance to it.  Marking something as "too localized" is the height of arrogance; it essentially says "because I can't imagine a situation in which some other developer would profit from an answer to this question, no such situation exists," thus ascribing to oneself the quality of *omniscience*.  It's not even funny how many times I've had some problem, Googled for a solution, found a SO link that describes the issue quite well, and seen it closed as "too localized" by a few developers too lazy to figure out the problem who insist on screwing it up for the rest of us.

Comment: Im coming into this question a bit late, this is what i found when i realised the options wasn't there so here goes. What would you suggest doing with a question like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115754/ancestry-gem-rails-5
cc @MasonWheeler

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The close reason you want is this one:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Under the "Off topic" sub dialog.

It gives more information that the old "too localised" reason which people found confusing when dealing with questions localised in **time** rather than place.

Comment: tl;dr: it was renamed to off-topic.

Comment: I must say, it is not a great alternative to "too localized". It emphasises non-reproducibility and typos. I would never have guesses that this was a suitable substitute.

Comment: @juanchopanza because it isn't one.

Comment: @user3477950 But it is being billed as one here, hence the comment.

Comment: @juanchopanza sure it is being proposed, and I am not disagreeing with your comment at all.

Comment: today I wanted to flag a question 'too localised', but did not find that. But somehow my sixth sense led to flag that question with what is said here :-)

Answer (score 8):

This one could be used

[image]

"can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: What if it can still be reproduced, is not the result of a simple typographical error, but is of no value to future visitors? I think that is what the OP really wants to know

Comment: I agree, these are two completely different use-cases.

Comment: @PlasmaHH If it is too localized then isn't it likely to not be reproduced by others?

Comment: @codeMagic: Besides that "no longer be" seems to imply that it once was reproducible, "too localized" can very well mean "yeah, you dumped us 500 lines of code, we can compile it, it crashes here too, and you have at least 20 stupid mistakes in there that are all so basic that for each of them there is surely a much broader question around that handles it". imho questions involving code and being "too localized" should probably go to codereview, as it is of almost no value to some future visitors to see that someone in his avl tree implementation forgot to initialize a pointer somewhere.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I guess it is on how you look at the close reason and, yes, the close votes aren't always going to cover every situation. So, it was reproducible by the OP but it cannot be reproduced by anyone else so it is no longer reproducible  by future visitors. That is why I think this close reason would suit the question. And, yes, it shouldn't be on SO but maybe Code Review which is why it would be voted on to close.

Comment: @codeMagic: Ah, so you say "reproducible" includes the OP? I was always assuming that it was meaning everyone else, as in "the OP produced it, everyone else failed to re-produce it". I wonder if changing the wording to something that emphasizes the "everyone else" part would make sense.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I would say it would cover both and that allows it to cover too localized also. I'm sure the original and foremost reason is what you were thinking. You could propose a [tag:feature-request] to change the wording if others agree with my thoughts on it. But all of the CV reasons could be changed and changed again all the time when new examples arise.

Comment: +0; red circles aren't freehand.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat they would have been but I ran out of ink in my pen

Comment: @codeMagic Oh, okay. That's fine. +1

Answer (score 8):

Consider down voting the question. Being not useful has always been one of the suggested reasons (given by the tool tip on the down vote button) for down voting.

Comment: After reading your answer, I was tempted to downvote you *in accordance with your own answer*, I thought. Then I found you have smartly said that the suggested reason for down voting is *'being not useful ...'*, and not something like *'not correctly answering'* or *'not addressing the question'*. So I up vote you. Made sense? :-) :-)