# Behavior on questions caused by typographical errors

Tags: discussion

Recently, a poster submitted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308105/update-error-with-insufficient-parameters-supplied-to-the-command/23308164?noredirect=1#comment35683859_23308164) and, after a search inside a long single line sql query text, I (and others) have found the typographical error that originated its error.

Of course, I have voted to close the question as `a simple typographical error`, but I have also written a very short answer (I admit that this answer will be of no great use to future readers, unless they stumble on it searching for the exact error string)

Another user wrote a comment implying that giving an answer on a typo is not a good thing.  (At least, I am implying that its comment is a request to not write answers in these cases)

I am now questioning myself if, in these contexts, the right behavior is to not give any kind of answer limiting myself to a simple comment or still give the answer and vote to close the question.

Comment: I'd explain the typo in a comment and vote-to-close.  YMMV.

Comment: @devnull, what is YMMV?

Comment: @AmitJoki: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ymmv

Comment: "Only a typo - vote-to-close" is likely to become over-used. I'd say that it should not have been closed because a closed question is implicitly worthless. Fact is that someone searching for a solution to the problem in the title would get a strong clue that *their* problem may be a simple typo, saving a repeat of the scenario. Naturally, that makes the rather rash assumption that people will search before lodging a plea for help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a close reason over in "Off Topic" which you've correctly used:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple **typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

That close reason used to be labeled "Too Localized" until a few months ago:

[Where did "too localized" go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go/)

Imho answering these questions regardless (whether as an answer or a comment) to highlight the typo is more helpful and welcoming than just closing without a comment.

Arguably, not everyone might agree. Answering such questions can send the implicit message that SO is a "please help me debug this code" site. But then, I'd argue the damage has been done for a while. (Indeed, I'd certainly qualify as one in the [apathetic group users highlighted here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/417194).)

Comment: I'm in the latter camp. IMHO, answering these questions is detrimental regardless of how many times Johnny has previously jumped off the bridge. The only way to start to repair the damage is to close these questions and delete them. SO was never meant to be a mechanical turk syntax checker.

Comment: Hehe. I used to be as well ([see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178234/filter-to-only-see-questions-asked-by-users-who-provided-answers)) but in light of how I got down voted for feature requests that seemed like obviously desirable to me, I've long abandoned the idea of improving this sewers. Heck, I don't even know why I'm even participating on meta.

Comment: [from #1 to #4](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/839601)? :)

Comment: @gnat: Pretty much so, yeah, with admittedly occasional trips that bordered on #3 at points when I was bored and had nothing more interesting to do.

Answer (score 13):

The close reason is pretty explicit; we aren't syntax checkers.

Answering these questions (even via a comment) simply invites more "give me teh fish" (non) questions from the OP and future new users.

If you really want to answer I personally would not tell them the answer directly, but rather how to go about *finding* the problem. That has value for future visitors that arrive via searching for the same (syntax) error message. It also teaches the OP to fish, rather than how to come to SO and get free fish handed to them.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the "vote to close + comment explaining the typo to the OP" approach opens a window of opportunity for opportunists to exploit the comment-answer before sufficient close votes can accrue (unless of course you are a gold badge holder on the tag).

[In this instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341235/incorrect-syntax-near-error-for-scalar-value), the OP had agreed to delete the question, but seemingly another upvoted answer arrived before he was able to do same.