# Should I flag a question if the problem is just a typo?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I recently saw this question here: [Error while reading a data from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041253/error-while-reading-a-data-from-a-file/25041328#25041328)

The issue is mind-numbingly simple; the poster simply spelled the name of a file wrong and got a `FileNotFoundException` as a result.

My question is, should these kinds of issues be flagged as Very Low Quality or something similar?

It seems like a question like this doesn't add much to the site and is probably far too specific to the particular problem to help anyone else.

What's the best way to deal with something like this? Also, please note that I'm not interested in handling answers to the question, but rather the question itself.

---

OK, the specific question turned out to be a combination of the typo and something else, but let's pretend for the sake of discussion that the typo was the only problem.

---

EDIT: My question is not a duplicate of [Behavior on questions caused by typographical errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252256/behavior-on-questions-caused-by-typographical-errors), or at least I believe it is not, as that question is more focused on whether or not one should answer the question as opposed to flag it.

Comment: Down-vote. That's enough.

Comment: Close as "cannot be reproduced" or whatever the similar close reason is now. It also wouldn't hurt to leave a comment to point out the issue. IMHO, a downvote isn't warranted if the question itself was structured well.

Comment: How about a downvote on the grounds of "Question does not show research effort"? Would that be justified?

Comment: Sometime, obvious errors are the hardest to find... not for lack of research. I wouldn't downvote it, just flag.

Comment: @asrivat1 Such questions may or may not demonstrate sufficient research effort; that will vary.  The "not useful" metric however will almost always apply here, as these questions will virtually never be useful to anyone else.

Comment: Ok, that does sound reasonable. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @gnat I disagree; that question is more focused on whether one should answer the question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can flag/vote to close the question using the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Not seeing that reason when trying to flag a question... but I remember seeing it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It's a sub-reason of "offtopic".

Comment: I knew I had seen it!