# Is this question on-topic?

Tags: support, close-reasons

The question linked below is a type of question that (I feel) appears often in the Perl tag: People want free code to solve a problem. The question itself is not about programming, it is entirely about the problem, so the answer would be to provide the entire code needed to solve the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/24911070/725418

I saw that it had 3 close votes, so I thought I would add one more. But I found that the 3 registered votes were for the reason "Unclear what you are asking", which felt totally wrong to me. It was not unclear at all. My understanding was that this was off-topic for stackoverflow.com, because it was not about programming. So I clicked that option, and found this:

[image: close reasons off-topic sub dialogue]

The "this is not about programming, it is about your problem" does not appear to be here. Indeed, it says in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that you are allowed to ask about

> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Does that mean that the above question, and others like it, now are on-topic?

Comment: Yup, it's off topic. And I was the last one to vote. I did leave a comment on the post.

Comment: Strongly related: [Where did “too localized” go?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252034/464709)

Comment: "Plzsendthecodes" is off-topic. I usually close these as "too broad" or with a custom close reason.

Comment: Wait, hold on. Is your (this) question about if the linked post is on-topic or not, or about the close options?

Comment: @gunr2171 Not sure if I see the distinction you are trying to make there. What I have written is what my question is. Though I am also asking for general direction for these types of questions. Are they meant to be closed as "unclear"? Because that feels wrong to me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would not say it is too localized either. Any text matching can be changed to fit a number of different sort of matches. These questions may have merit, but I am asking for the official opinion.

Comment: The linked question is indeed "unclear". What is the question the OP is asking? Yes, there is an implied "how do I do this?", but that's generally not good enough, and shows lack of effort. Take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24913219/1), where the comments are "good for you" and "cool story". This is a Q&A site, the first thing you have to do is ask a question.

Comment: @gunr2171 Well, that sounds as though you are saying that the question would have been fine if he had added `How do I get the expected output?`

Comment: @TLP, if the OP added that phrase, it would be a question, yes, but it would be "too broad". If the OP _also_ added what they have attempted, it would probably be a question that would not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you can interpret this one.

1. Since they're asking you to write an entire program for you, it's **too broad**.  We're here to answer specific questions about specific problems.  Writing complete programs is broader than that scope.
2. Maybe you can assume that they've attempted to solve this problem and are stuck.  If you lurk on some of these sorts of questions, you'll find that this actually sometimes is the case.  In this case you can interpret it as **unclear what you're asking**, because you don't know **what** they're stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [right way to ask for code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660127/faster-way-to-swap-endianness-in-c-sharp-with-32-bit-words).

In general, questions asking for code should demonstrate *a minimal knowledge of the subject matter* (don't confuse this with "demonstration of effort").  Often, that takes the form of the OP posting his attempt at solving the problem, but it doesn't necessarily have to.  If a code request is clear, specific and answerable, it's a perfectly good question for Stack Overflow, especially if it's code that might be of interest to others.

The question you linked has none of these characteristics.  All it states are the inputs and outputs.  It is essentially a work order.