# What to do with "too localized" questions in help queue?

Tags: discussion, help-improvement

I've just started using the Help and Improvement queue and would like to get some feedback on my actions. I'm running into a lot of questions that are generally just typos combined with users that are pretty clueless about compiler errors. Here are some examples:

- [I need to find substring index in string and if doesn`t exist returned result must be -1 in Java (web service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137127/i-need-to-find-substring-index-in-string-and-if-doesnt-exist-returned-result-mu)
- [Problems with static when invoking to an asyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140641/problems-with-static-when-invoking-to-an-asynctask)

Basically, the question exists because they are really new programmers that can't read a compiler error and understand what the error is trying to tell them to change. I can't see how these questions could help anyone besides the OP in this one, singular scenario.

Based on [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go), it seems like I should be giving them a close vote since they are off-topic and not going to help future users. However, in the review window, there's a link that says `question is very low quality`, which asks me if I want to flag the question. Should I be voting to close as well as flagging as low quality? Just close vote?

Comment: A close vote should be enough IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Just send it back to triage with the "question is very low quality"-option if it was mis-triaged.

Optionally, open it in a new window beforehand to add a close-vote and maybe also downvote.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it should just be a close vote.  I right click on the title and open the post in a new tab.  Then I flag it for closure and then skip it in the HIQ.  I know this is more work than having something right there in the queue but it is the only way I can find as of now to get close-able post out of the HIQ.

Comment: As Deduplicator has answered, [there is a "this is very low quality"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link?lq=1) option that can be used if necessary.

Comment: @JoshCaswell but that puts it back through the triage review queue.  I believe that going to the question and close voting it will add it to the close vote queue.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying, but I don't think that takes it _out_ of the HIQ. I don't know for sure, though -- it's not accounted for on Shog's flowchart. (Also, given the relative sizes of the Close queue and Triage, I'd think a VLQ will get dealt with faster via the latter.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I trust the close vote queue more though as the question originally went through triage and enough people picked should be improved instead of unsalvageable.