# Closing as a mental typo

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Here is the close reason we all know:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Increasingly I'm seeing questions which are caused by the **mental version** of a typographical error. In other words, whereas a typo is caused by twitchy keyboard fingers, I am talking about things caused by twitchy brain cells.

There are many better examples out there but [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575985/trying-to-loop-through-array-and-add-additional-key-value-pair-end-up-with-onl) I just ran into, where the user initialized a variable outside instead of inside the loop.

I've already been voting to close some of these with the "typo" reason, but feeling slighty guilty as I did so since they are not technically "typos", unless one expands the definition of "typo" to include putting two lines in the wrong order, or putting a `++` after the variable instead of before. Yet these questions have in common with real typos the fact that the resolution is unlikely to help future readers etc. The titles are almost never good descriptions of the problems and unlikely to bring someone to the question when searching, since they are usually of the form "Blah blah is not working".

How about changing this close reason to read:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical or **trivial logical** error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Note: This is distinct from [Where did "too localized" go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go), which is about the "too localized" close reason, which was thought by some to be too broad or subject to abuse.

Comment: The meat of this close reason is really: "this [question] was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." This applies to mistakes of any nature. Not all cases of PEBKAC are unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @BoltClock _" Not all cases of PEBKAC are unlikely to help future readers. "_ Good point.

Comment: @BoltClock If this applies to mistakes of any nature why not rephrasing the close reason to "...a simple error...".

Comment: Let's just rearrange the words so that the formerly second sentence (not likely to help) is now primary and the formerly first one merely lists the most common cases.

Comment: I like the idea, but I can also see this close reason becoming very subjective very quickly. As a side note, the first `or` should be a comma, and there should be a comma before the second `or`.

Comment: this can be summed up as **off-topic: brain fart**

Comment: `trivial logical error`, I am not so sure that `trivial` is correct semantically, it could be replaced with a more semantically applicable adjective like `careless`, `inattentive` ... and many other generic adjectives that all end up being just synonyms for `too localized` but assign blame. So `highly localized logic error` would be more correct in all these cases and then we are back to `off-topic: too localized` which was deemed *confusing, mean spirited, etc.* in the past, thus the `typo` close reason we have now replaces it in spirit at least.

Comment: I think it's more appropriate to close dup that question. Now, the problem is to find the duplicate...

Comment: @BoltClock If that is in fact the "meat" of the reason, the wording hides that fact very well. it states clearly in the first sentence that the problem is caused by a typographical error, and refers to the fact that the manner in which it was resolved being unlikely to help future readers as a **restriction** or additional qualification on the essential typo-based nature of the problem. Personally, I think that it is reasonable to make the non-future-helpfulness a or the primary qualification for this close reason, but I am just trying to say, as currently worded, that's not what it says.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson As a native English speaker, I find "trivial" far more clear and intuitive than any of the alternatives you suggest, and I don't find the usage of "trivial" to convey a blaming tone. I don't know if it's "by the book" usage (maybe a good question for English Lang & Usage), but it's entirely natural language. Extremely few native English programmers would be confused by it.

Comment: the definition of *trivial (of little value or importance)* is not semantically correct. If something causes an error it is by definition **not trivial** it is very ***important***, which is the exact opposite of *trivial*. If you are a native english speaker and do not understand why the semantics are incorrect there is not much I can do about that, you are confusing *simple*, or *basic* it seems; [YEINU](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2014/01/02/yeinu-your-experience-is-not-universal/) the definition of words is universally agreed upon and easily discovered using a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did "too localized" go?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go)

Comment: I think this would get misused far more often than it would be properly used.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson A "trivial logical error" means that the problem was a simple mistake that was probably not even intended by the author or would not have happened if they had thought it through a little harder. It *is* trivial because it's of no interest to anyone else. It was a simple logical error resulting from thinking incorrectly about a simple issue, and there is nothing interesting to be learned from it. It is therefore *completely* appropriate by your definition. Additionally, I think you have a misunderstanding of how language works if you think the definition of words is that rigid.

Comment: This is not a dupe. It's a feature request to change the wording on the close reason that *succeeded* "Too localized."

Comment: Huh, I consider these "typos" automatically. Never really gave it much thought tbh. Hard to disagree with the notion that we ought to find proper terminology to cover the lot.

Comment: I've heard these referred to as **thinkos**, which matches nicely with *typos*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson according to Merriam-Webster (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivial), the "simple definition" of trivial is indeed "not important".  However, the first entry in the "full definition" is "commonplace, ordinary".
I understand your point that an error is not unimportant, however I don't take this as saying that trivial applies to the consequences of the code, but rather to the skill required to find/fix the problem. Given that, perhaps instead of "trivial logic error" it should read "logic error with a trivial solution."

Answer (score 40):

> **off-topic: brain fart** - *This question was caused by a problem that was a simple, careless mistake and is **unlikely to help future readers**.*

#### All the other verbiage is just noise to 99% of the people that would make these simple careless mistakes to begin with.

---

That said, there used to be a `"How to use a debugger?"` question with useful answers describing how to debug things yourself, that was a dupe target for these kinds of questions, but it seems to be gone now as well.

Which is too bad, because getting something closed for this *typo* reason is hard, and there are lots of people that will vote to reopen things closed for this reason at the drop of a hat because they think it is a *"mean spirited"* reason to close things and/or that every question is sacred and deserves some kind of answer.

Comment: I guess that's too frank. At least if the bold part is visible to everyone. ;-)

Comment: I use similar expressions informally; nevertheless this is too coarse an expression to be adopted formally. Naturally I deny being prudish, hypocritical, etc.  as written and spoken languages are different and usually no one else is listening when I use the term. The aim of being inoffensive to everyone is difficult to achieve; nevertheless we should avoid expressions widely regarded as vulgar.

Comment: This reads like a rant. Please consider rewording somewhat.

Comment: "Brain Fart" is also known in the Jargon File as a [braino](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/b/braino.html).

Comment: Leave out "careless". Don't blame people.

Comment: @JanDoggen: I was just about to say that, too. Calling a mistake "Careless" is too aggressive.

Comment: simple careless mistake = an oversight, IMO. Something you missed because you're human.

Comment: I fail to understand why one should not use the word "careless" to refer to something which is careless. It's trigger warnings run amok. When people sign up, we should make them agree to a disclaimer that says, "Some things said in answers or comments on this site may hurt your feelings, especially if you're the overly sensitive type. Some posters are brusque and direct and even abrasive. It you don't think you'll be comfortable here, move on to a "safer" site."

Answer (score 27):

To build off of @BoltClock's comment, what if we reworded that close reason a bit to change the focus from typos to being unhelpful to future visitors:

> **Off-Topic: Resolution Unlikely to Help Others**: This question has been **resolved in a way that is unlikely to help others**.  It was caused
>   by a problem that can no longer reproduced, a typographical error or
>   other simple mistake.  While similar questions may be on-topic here,
>   this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.
>   This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the
>   shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

And possibly in the help center:

> **Why was my question closed as "Resolution Unlikely to Help Others"?**: We are striving here to gather questions and answers to
>   not only benefit the asker, but future visitors as well.  A question
>   that was closed with this reason means that others felt that because
>   of the way this question was resolved, it is unlikely to be useful to
>   future visitors.  Typical problems and resolutions include:
>
> - Problem is unable to be reproduced: Your compiler / editor is acting up and refuses to compile code that worked a few seconds ago. 
>     You restart your computer and everything is better.
> - Typographical errors: Getting a compile error because you started a string with double quotes and tried to close it with single quotes. 
>     Or using = instead of == in a conditional.  Etc.
> - Simple mistake: When you ask a question then realize that you got two lines out of order.  Or any other problem where taking a short
>     break and getting a coffee all of a sudden makes the problem obvious.
> - Etc.

This is just a rough idea (I'll let the word-smiths come up with something more professional / better worded), but the point I hope I have made is that if we emphasize that the question was **resolved** in a way **unlikely to help others**, the close reason will be clearer in it's intended usage and scope.

---

As I thought about this, I've decided that (at least in my head) this shall be known as the "Problems caused by cosmic rays or lack of coffee" reason or "Problem solved by power buttons and a fresh pot of coffee" reason.

Comment: I'd strongly support this. At risk of undermining my own argument, it would also be useful to close problems which are too specific to help anyone else in a less inappropriate way than 'Too broad' is used now. And yes, I am aware 'too localized' was unpopular and removed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an alternative viewpoint here...

I very much come under the category of 'programming enthusiast' and as such I make these sort of stupid errors reasonably often! As such they can't always be seen until someone points them out (or you step through it etc and have a D'oh!)

My point being that at the point somewhere between getting the error and fixing it (occasionally before debugging time, depending on how obvious the error is) I might stick it in a search engine.

If I end up here to see a similar (ly stupid) error, it might point me in the right direction to fixing it.

Sure they are frustrating as hell to answer sometimes, (I see the same sort of thing occasionally on the tags I do play in) because the stupidity level is so high, but that is only because you know the answer. The person asking, and the person searching for the answer doesn't.

Surely if someone is sitting there hacking away in $language and they run into a problem, it shouldn't matter that it is stupidly simple. If a duplicate exists then we should point it to that, if it doesn't it deserves answering because it might help me when I do something equally stupid.

Comment: *until you step through it* Why didn't you step through it before posting? *If a duplicate exists then we should point it to that* As already pointed out many times, the problem is that there IS no duplicate for the majority of such mental typos. *it might point me* It won't, because such questions are fundamentally unsearchable. Most have titles like "My program is not working".

Comment: @torazaburo because my debugging process usually follows the path of least effort - oh I've got an error message, I'll throw it into google. Oh there's no sensible results, I guess I'll have to debug then... oh I wanted a test not an assign in that if statement - D'oh! (add missing equals sign and hope nobody was watching)

Comment: to answer your actual question ;) I doubt I would post a question like that, I've usually done a little due diligence prior to that. That doesn't mean I'm not grateful to find other's who have asked those questions beforehand. (although one step on the way to solving a problem can be ask a potentially stupid question, then either it gets an answer or you solve the problem and post the answer)

Answer (score 0):

### Such questions *can* be valuable, but certainly aren't inherently

Stack Overflow is about questions that can help future visitors. The fact that OP was able to solve the problem by thinking harder (or that others who saw the question *believe that* OP *should be able to* solve the problem that way), does not imply that other people couldn't genuinely have a legitimate problem along the same lines.

I generally apply the following three-pronged test:

- Can the actual problem (not whatever OP initially might have thought the problem was) be described in a way that makes a coherent, searchable title?
- Is there an *even vaguely plausible* misunderstanding that other people could actually have, that would lead to reproducing the problem?
- Is there a clear, proper MRE (or can one be produced by editing, without destroying intent) specifically about the problem? (In particular: whatever it is that OP got wrong, the code should *not also* include a section where OP got *the same thing right*.)

**When all of these conditions are met, the question should IMO stay open.** Questions like this can help someone who is at a lower skill/knowledge level than the OP.

For example: it's very common for beginners writing a "counting" loop to put the "reset the counter" code inside the loop, such that the counter only ends up with a value of 0 or 1 instead of whatever value it should have reached. A canonical for "how do I write a loop to count occurrences of something in an input sequence?" (phrasing adjusted as appropriate for the language) is a perfectly reasonable [beginner-oriented canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426205/) to have, and a canonical answer to the "how-to" question would do well to address common pitfalls including that exact logic error. (That's why I wrote a separate "common pitfalls" answer [when I made this canonical Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666408).) Alternately, the problem might be more common in languages that have a separate mechanism to declare variables (like `int count = 0;`) - the author of the code might expect that because this is "only an initialization" that the assignment of `0` would only occur the first time, and that putting this line inside the loop is appropriate in order to scope the variable. That's something that could be cleared up by a (possibly existing) Q&A about initialization vs. assignment, or about the semantics of that variable-declaration statement.

Comment: IOW: (1) salvageable? (2) likely to help others? (3) clear/specific? -- under "likely to help others" I would also require it to be *findable*. many beginner mistakes are impossible to search for, mostly because beginners have no idea what they did, or they don't know how to describe the issue (many don't even spend any thought on the error message they're getting).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm of two minds on that. Ideally, yes, the question should be findable directly by the person who needs it. But - if a quality answer (= beginner-understandable explanation) is possible, I would greatly prefer to have a canonical duplicate available, because beginners **will ask again anyway** even if they have no idea what to search for - *especially because* they have no idea what to search for. That makes closing questions faster, reduces the effort involved in commenting, and puts the needed information in front of the right eyeballs.

Comment: canonicals are a great solution but I wish this site better supported us in finding them. you all but have to memorize the most common canonicals, or come up with taxonomy and enforce it, because the search function cannot be relied upon do unearth anything useful. SO wants to deploy more AI. that'd be a worthy problem to solve for them. what's there so far usually fails me.