# Are questions relevant to only one person off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Quite often, beginners' questions are about trivial mistakes. A good answer to such a question can be very useful to the person asking.

On the other hand, I would say there is a very low chance of another beginner with the same misunderstanding coming to the same situation and finding the existing question and answer.

Therefore, we can make a distinction between two types of questions:

1. questions which are useful to the community, e.g. [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)
2. questions which can help one person, e.g. [create the for loop in the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577338/create-the-for-loop-in-the-variable)

If SO is about *making a data base* of programming questions & answers, then the latter is off-topic.

On the other hand, if it is about *giving answers to questions* about programming, then both are on-topic.

Which is it? **Is there a written policy addressing this?**

### EDIT

Question [Closing as a mental typo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo) assumes that #2 is off-topic as *"no longer reproducible"* and proposes changing the description of *"no longer reproducible"* reason wording to explain that.

If such questions are off-topic, **when do they become *"no longer reproducible"***? After being answered or before that?

In other words, should the OP be given a chance to get a useful answer before the question is closed? Or do we care only about the *"future readers"*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A good answer to such a question can be very useful to the person asking.

That's not the criteria for good questions or answers. Stack Overflow isn't meant as a *personal help-desk*.

If the question or answers aren't likely to be helpful in future research, these should be closed.

> Which is it? Is there a written policy addressing this?

You answered that yourself already:

> If SO is about making a data base of programming questions & answers, then the latter is off-topic.

It's actually available in written form, when you enter [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> > Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.