# Closing feature requests as duplicates of general discussions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, meta

### Given a general discussion about a problem, and a feature request proposing a solution to the problem, should the feature request be closed as a duplicate of the discussion?

There seems to be a common trend of feature requests being closed as duplicates of discussions, simply because the topic has been discussed at some point.

The problem that I see is that, when doing this, you're voting "No" on the feature request, then disallowing anyone else to have a say unless the question is reopened (recourse that is not available to users with less than 3,000 reputation).

#### This discussion excludes feature requests that are only tagged incorrectly (and actually propose the same feature)

Comment: Depends on the context. Many questions tagged "discussion" are in fact feature requests, or *also* feature requests, and vice versa.

Comment: I don't buy that. The devs don't look at discussions as if they are feature requests. As well, they are treated differently by the community. How people vote, comment and answer, as well as the number of views the question gets is completely dependent on the tags the question uses. In my opinion, closing a feature request as a duplicate of a general discussion is unfair to the feature request.

Comment: It still really depends on the context I think. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Given a general discussion about a problem, and a feature request proposing a solution to the problem, should the feature request be closed as a duplicate of the discussion?

Comment: You should consider adding that more specific statement to your question, @TinyGiant, because my formulation went more like "Downvoters should comment" -> "Why is voting anonymous?" (That is, a feature proposal that goes contrary to well-established policy.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Honestly even in your example, what is the problem with letting voting take it's course and simply referencing the discussion in the comments of the feature request? I'd love to get your input on the discussion in the comments on pekka's answer below.

Comment: I don't think that a blanket can be made for either option here, @TinyGiant: I would agree with Deduplicator's "It depends".

Comment: @JoshCaswell More specifically then: If the feature request is "require comments on downvotes" (for this example lets imagine that there are no duplicate feature requests) what is the issue with leaving it open and allowing the community to vote on the request? Why is it absolutely necessary that the question be closed as soon as possible? Do you not trust the voting community to vote correctly?

Comment: The same as with any duplicate closure: smearing out the information across multiple pages where it's harder to find. The same as it would be on the main site: if I post "Dictionary won't stay sorted" (which happens to be a debugging question), the answer is that I'm missing a fundamental point, which is found thoroughly explained under "How do I sort a dictionary?" (which happens to be an implementation question). But again, I think this only applies in some cases, generally those where hell would freeze over before the request was implemented.

Comment: And, as I'm sure you know, everyone can still vote up and down when the request is closed -- and more importantly, can vote up and down on the answers to the discussion question. (Also, it's not particularly clear, especially lately, that voting on feature requests actually has any effect on which ones are implemented.)

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate vote on "Closing as a mental typo", for instance.

Comment: But that's the same situation as the "Require downvoters to comment" -> "Why is voting anonymous?" closing. The discussion gives information on why voting is anonymous and comments are not required, but it does not address the proposed feature of requiring downvoters to comment. The person requesting the feature is not asking why something is, they are asking for it to be changed. @JoshCaswell

Answer (score 5):

As so often, the answer is: It depends.

If the [discussion] thoroughly deconstructs the feature requested and the consensus was "No!", there's no use in duplicating it in the feature-request.
It might be appropriate to answer the FR with a short summary if that specific feature is overwhelmed by other things, but otherwise any duplication is pointless.

If the [discussion] is just a [feature-request] in disguise, consider editing it to clarify things.

Which leaves discussions which are discussions, are far more wide-ranging, and either don't sufficiently focus on that point, or at least don't show that the feature would be detrimental to SO.

Answer (score 4):

> Given a general discussion about a problem, and a feature request
>   proposing a solution to the problem, should the feature request be
>   closed as a duplicate of the discussion?

If the discussion provides a succinct reason for the rejection of the feature request (ideally, in the highest upvoted answer) then yes, it's absolutely ok to close.

I would heavily encourage folks to write an answer instead, though. It comes across much less condescending than just closing as a dupe, and it gives the OP a chance to make an argument for their idea that would likely just be lost in the noise in the original discussion.

But doing this is voluntary, not a requirement.

Comment: If you're doing this you're basically voting no for the feature request while disallowing any other user to have a say unless it gets reopened. What harm is there in simply downvoting? Why does the question *need* to be closed. Why not let voting take it's course? If you are correct and the feature request should be rejected, will the communities votes not show that anyway? What's to say that the active users today have the same opinion as the users who were active three years ago? What's to say that the problem is really the same as it was back then?

Comment: [Yet another feature request being closed as a duplicate of a discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313884/4639281).

Comment: @Tiny Well, I came over that FR too, and I don't see closing there as reasonable, as asking where an old reason went and wanting to clarify its replacement's scope aren't all that similar.

Comment: @Deduplicator This kind of closing seems to happen on a regular basis, your answer, and pekka's basically say that it is perfectly fine to do so.

Comment: Yes, it happens often (how much of that is confirmation-bias on my side?), especially on meta, though no less with other reasons. And this answer does not condone that.

Comment: Nothing here says that it shouldn't be done either. It's rude and obnoxious, but no one seems to have a problem with it. Keep in mind that the situation I linked here is exactly the situation mentioned in my question here. @Deduplicator

Comment: Honestly, even if a proposed change was not well received during a discussion, what is the problem with leaving the feature request open and allowing voting to take its course? If the opinion is still the same as it was then, the request will be downvoted and nothing will come of it all the same. There *is* harm in closing a positively received feature request in this manner though.

Comment: @TinyGiant the beauty of meta is there is more than enough experienced users to reopen questions if they are closed incorrectly.  But I agree with the answers here - a blanket "no closing feature requests as dups of discussions" is bad policy because the answer to the feature request may be in the discussion.  No need to spread the discussion out in multiple posts.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Correction: **an** answer to the feature request may be found in the discussion, not **the** answer to the feature request. An answer to a feature request is an opinion statement on the requested feature, possibly with objective arguments to back up the opinion. That is a reason to reference discussions in the comments of feature requests, not a reason to close them. A feature request is not a discussion, it is a request for a feature that may spawn discussion on the proposed feature, but it is not a discussion post.

Answer (score 0):

There are three strong reasons why I believe we shouldn't close bugs, support and FR as duplicates of discussions:

1. **If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.** This establish a hard line between discussions and everything else. `if (!x) then {y}`. We can have discussions about a problem along with brainstorming several solutions, it is loose, and can be not even technical, but in FR's/bugs someone has to define exactly how they pretend to change *technical* stuff, how people interact with the site.
2. **Oscillation**. Community can change its mind around several topics, from saying "not a problem" to "a solution we need". Sometimes we agree there's a problem but not so hot about the proposed solution(s). Other times, we think we need to change something but aren't sure of the possible implications (like RFC, feedback requests).
3. **The practical reason**. Community managers and developers have a dashboard of sorts for all bugs and feature requests *network wide*. Something like MSE [bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bugs) and [reqs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=requests) tabs. I guess that closing FR's and bugs may push those down the queue.

Comment: You know, if the discussion no longer captures the community's consensus, there's nothing stopping you from reopening. As long as it does, and the consensus is NO, there's no reason to bug the devs with it, and thus duplicate the discussion. Of course, if a FR is mistagged as a discussion, feel free to correct that.

Comment: @Deduplicator actually there's something stopping me, reputation.

Comment: Well, it was a more generic *you*. And when you get a bit more rep, it also includes you. ;-) (Honestly, I ignored your current rep completely...)

Comment: @Deduplicator I know. I was pulling you one ;)

Comment: Well done, I needed it too ;-)

Answer (score -2):

In general, I think don't think feature-requests should be closed as duplicates of discussions.  But this is only because I think meta questions are often mistagged.  Let's examine some possible scenarios:

- **New feature request is poorly researched and not well defined**.  In these cases, I would have no problem closing a "feature-request" as a duplicate of the general discussion because it wouldn't actually bring anything new to the table.  In some regards, **these "feature-requests" are mistagged** because the implementation details aren't thought out, and they don't truly request a feature beyond what what discussed already.  And upon properly retagging the question as a discussion, the duplicate votes become totally justified.  The "require comment for downvote" requests generally fit this category because the requests are usually little more than complaints without any new idea for an alternative system.
- **Feature request is truly distinct but gets duplicate votes anyway**.  This is probably the category where most of the requests you are concerned about fall under, and it's very similar to how any other borderline duplicate is handled.  It probably shouldn't be marked as a duplicate in the first place, but the request probably won't have trouble being reopened if it is actually closed. A simple rephrasing or other emphasis of the important aspects of the request will make it more obvious that the request is a specific proposal and not a general discussion.

  It might be annoying to have to explicitly address every duplicate aspect of the request, but it's not a wasted effort by any means.  A well thought-out feature-request explains why it's worthwhile and (to a certain extent) how it could be accomplished, and I doubt that these would be closed as a duplicate.

I do think that even when a previous discussion proves that a feature request is a bad idea (or even impossible) that the feature request should *not* be closed as a duplicate.  Instead, a contrary answer with the previous discussion as a reference is better.

Comment: Good answer, I like that you actually addressed situations where they should not be closed instead of just ignoring that part of the question like most the of other answers here.

Comment: One thing I've been thinking about, if it is a feature request like "require users to comment on downvotes" where it has obviously been requested before, would it not be more constructive to reference the "why are downvotes anonymous?" question in the comments, but close it as a duplicate of a previous feature request that is requesting the same feature? And if there isn't one for that feature request, leave it open to be voted on so the next time one comes around it can be closed as a duplicate of a feature request that is requesting the same feature?

Comment: @TinyGiant yes that is what I think should happen.  Actual suggestions like the "require downvotes" should be marked duplicates of other feature-requests.  At that point, the why ("voting is anonymous") will be part of the duplicate target's contrary responses.  If there is no such request, then I like leaving them open to being answered properly (the answers should probably reference previous discussion).  Finally, some "feature requests" are so poorly thought out that they (almost) should be retagged as discussions.  Then a duplicate to a discussion still makes sense.

Comment: It's good to hear that someone else sees things from a similar point of view as me. I like the point about the feature request being tagged incorrectly, we get plenty of feature requests that are really just rants on some perceived injustice, but we also get lots of feature requests that are well formulated, which are then closed as a duplicate of some old discussion that touched on the topic.