# Confusing tab navigation on the new Stack Overflow authentication form

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, login, user-experience

I paid attention that recently the login form at Stack Overflow has undergone a lifting. Everything is OK besides one thing — the user experience of the <kbd>TAB</kbd>-navigation.

Type an username, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and you expect to be able to type a password immediately after the first <kbd>TAB</kbd>, but instead, you are focused on "Forgot password?" link:

[image]

It would be better to restore the classical order of the <kbd>TAB</kbd>-navigation:

1. User name
2. TAB #1
3. Password
4. TAB #2
5. Login button
6. TAB #3
7. Password recovery

P.S. It's not a duplicate of [Can't auto login with Keepass anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381320/7795130) (although it is related to the same UI-element, but from another perspective) since that question is focused on the compatibility of Stack Overflow with the third-party software, while my question is about regression in UX after a redesign.

**Postfix update:**
The problem is fixed, but why does the <kbd>TAB</kbd>-navigation from the *Password* field leads to the *Forgot password?* and not to the *Log in* button? Isn't more logical by default to forward the focus of the <kbd>TAB</kbd>-navigation to the *Log in* button rather than to *Forgot password?*. The password recovery is much less frequent scenario.

Comment: Forgot password links usually is below password textbox... as forgetting password normally occurs less often then typing it. Maybe they wanted to save some space ? Also it's possible for them to just let it there make it... let's say (tab wise) so why not just do that ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier saving space is fine, that doesn't mean it should drop the ball on having an UI to adheres to the least astonishment rule. They should introduce tab order then.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, I'm not aware about SO designers intention, but I know that everytime I pass an auth, I have this issue and it is a horrible UX decision.

Comment: @rene Yeah, I agree, it's not like... asking for too much

Comment: @Stijn I can't find any precedence of us closing feature requests as duplicates of bug reports, is this something we do? I know there was a big stink a while back about closing [feature requests as duplicates of related discussion questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313903/7795130). I would think they're duplicates like you suggested because a solution to either will solve the other, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It may sound weird, but IMO, the other question should be marked as duplicate of THIS one. Since this one is identifying the problem better.

Comment: Still not as bad as the tab ordering inside Win10's [WIN]+[TAB]...it can't even be bothered to maintain the same order forwards and backwards...

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Pressing “tab” in log-in form switches to “Forgot password?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325271/289905).

Comment: No, the second tab should land on the "Log in" button.

Comment: It's fixed but not optimally, after password field the tab navigation leads to the _Forgot password_ and not to the _Log in_ button!

Answer (score 3):

The SE team has, thankfully, fixed this. Rather than using `tabindex` though they have an interesting approach [documented on the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325543/145951): natural DOM source order + reversing the visual order using `flex-box`.