# Python questions about indentation: Answer? Close as dupe?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, canonical

In [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), indentation is very important:

```
>>> for i in [1, 2, 3]:
... print(i)

  File "<input>", line 2
    print(i)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

>>> for i in [1, 2, 3]:
...     print(i)
...     
... 
1
2
3
>>>
```

However, [questions about the `IndentationError` have been asked so many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aanswer+title%3AIndentationError), I want to know how to handle them:

1. Close as dupe, because questions like them have been asked & answered so many times?
2. Answer it, because almost every question about indentation is different?

---

Let's check some examples:

- [Python formatting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624265/python-formatting-error)
- [Indentationerror: unexpected indent python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503395/indentationerror-unexpected-indent-python)

And so on...

Comment: It is not very clear why you would not consider voting dup when a perfectly good duplicate exists.  Is perhaps the real reason that you don't want to dig through 97 dups to find the best one?  Well, who does.  Just move on.

Comment: See [Closing as a mental typo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo).

Comment: @Deduplicator: Lol (about that **brain fart** :P). Well, are you talking about vote to close it as: *I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a simple problem which is about the indent. You should try a debugger and check what's wrong and how to fix it.* ?

Comment: Really the only indentation error that might deserve its own question is when the error is about matching indentation levels caused by mixing tabs and spaces in the source code in an editor that doesn't display these well. Other than that, they are pretty much all identical and should be easily answerable by a single, canonical source.

Comment: @Dannnno: Huh, I should answer another question about the indentation problem which has clear title and content (I'll self ask one if it's needed), and use it as dupe target for other questions like it ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the duplicate should be the other way around, this Q is from 2016 while the dup target is from 2020.

Comment: @bad_coder that [isn't a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938) in the main space and shouldn't be one on Meta either.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't see how the duplicate target is better than this post and antiquity is a factor in favor of this Q. The last post you linked is just an opinion, with plenty of threads out there in favor of keeping the older threads as the main reference.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Otherwise what you'll get are users trying to write **unnecessary walls-of-text** only to try to outdo older and sufficient threads instead of improving them. That's just unnecessary noise and unnecessary arguing to what can and should be kept simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The example you've created should be considered to be closed as a duplicate since there is a clear error message in the code that would show that the code is affected by the same issue as others.

It gets a bit more difficult with other questions where you need to start doing guesswork to figure out whether the op's just not included the right indentation in their question

```
if something_equals_true:
    print 1
print 2
```

You'll often find questions where the op includes a more intricate version of the above where the op only wants to print both if something is true in which case pointing to a duplicate won't really help much. Now you could possibly vtc as a typographical error but you very often struggle to find 4 like minded people so its kind of based off your own opinion whether or not you think it deserves an answer.