# Question where author had wrong end of stick

Tags: support

[EntityFramework and FluentAPI working with ComplexTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044567/entityframework-and-fluentapi-working-with-complextypes)

The question is "EntityFramework and FluentAPI working with ComplexTypes"
but the answer is "that's not a complex type".

The result is a question that is a google-trap for people who actually do want to know how to work with both.

What to do?

Comment: It looks like that question already has an answer on it saying that the premise is wrong, if you don't feel that that answer explains it well enough you could always add your own

Comment: Yeah, that ends up being a rather useless Q/A pair, unless Tomaszewski's mistake is a common one. A good candidate for closure as the non-existent "too localized" reason. Maybe "can no longer be reproduced" would be appropriate? Aside from that, if you think there's a good Q/A pair that can be generated here for future Googlers, ask a new question.

Comment: @Sayse the existing answer is fine.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks that sounds right, the only thing is too-localized isn't a close option any more, suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you could create an answer like, "If the OP was using ComplexTypes, they'd need to do..." so the info is there. It might be better to create a self-answered Q&A where the Q actually uses ComplexTypes.

Comment: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.` ?

Comment: "Too localized" was been removed for good reason. Please don't try to fill that void by misusing other close reasons.  It's not a great question, but it absolutely does not deal with trying to reproduce a problem.  The answerer was able to understand where the asker had a problem.  The problem lied in the asker's misunderstanding of complex types. The answerer provided a useful answer clarifying the confusion.  Is it too localized? Yes.  Is it an issue that couldn't be reproduced or understood? No, the problem was clear, and the answerer addressed it.

Comment: If anything, give it a better title such as "Confusion about mapping Complex Types in EF"

Comment: It is useful, since many people already confuse C# value/reference types.  EF/SQL complex types add a whole other dimension to that confusion.  Clearly the asker thought a class qualified as a complex type. I would say there's a good likely hood others will stumble upon the same confusion, but maybe not in quite the same way.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, I'm afraid I'm even less clear what to do now so I'll leave it for the mods to sort out should they feel like it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the title of the question to better match its contents (e.g. "How do I get Fluent API to work with this class?").  Optionally, create your own Q/A pair under the original title (or a similar title), so that people looking for that question will have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could rename the title to be more accurate to the problem but then it would not be any more useful because it is a [**mental typo**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo), unless this is some extremely ubiquitous source of confusion, and then if it is it should be **very easy** to find a suitable **duplicate**.

Either way all roads lead to **vote to close** and probably **vote to delete**.