# Closing questions with typos faster: typo-hammer?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, dupehammer, typographical-error

When a question with a problem caused entirely by an obvious typo appears, the proper course of action is to close it. Unfortunately, it takes several minutes or longer to gather the five votes required to put the question on hold. This is more than enough for users who have no access to close/reopen votes to type up their answers, especially because these answers tend to be rather short. Even worse, some of these answers quickly gather an upvote or two, preventing OP from deleting the question.

I think it would be beneficial to expedite closing of questions with typos in some way. For example, we could let users with gold badges in a tag close questions with typos the "dupe-hammer style".

Enabling typo-hammer has several prerequisites:

- We need to work out a better definition of what we collectively consider a typo
- We need to move "cannot reproduce" into a separate category
- Closing comment on the typo category needs to become mandatory

In order to mitigate the risk of closing as typos by mistake, gold badge holders should get the power to reopen questions closed as typos with a single vote in the same way that they can reopen duplicates.

I think that an additional benefit of having typo-hammer in place is making participants more reluctant to answer questions caused by typos.

Comment: We'd have to be ***very*** careful here...there's a world of difference between a typo error and a "cannot reproduce" issue...at the moment the two are conjoined - *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."*

Comment: What if the problem wasn't caused by the typo after all, though? That tends to happen.

Comment: The first is obvious, the second just means that there might be factors *not yet edited into the question*  that could improve the question overall.

Comment: Typo hammer?  You mean Moljrin?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The problem with questions that have typos is that they pollute the site, making legitimate answers harder to find. There are many questions caused by missing semicolons or semicolons inserted in wrong places, often with multiple answers saying the same exact thing. As far as solving OP's problem goes, a single comment would be just as helpful.

Comment: I would like to see a whole Home Depot-full of hammers available.  The 'Elitist, Hostile Hammer from Hell' would be a good start, rapidly followed by the 'Bone-Idle Ball-Peen' and 'Homework Dump Hide Hammer'.

Comment: Martin demonstrates pretty well why SE doesn't trust users with such a weapon.

Comment: What if the typo.. is a typo? ^_^

Comment: `This is more than enough for users who have no access to close/reopen votes to type up their answers` I don't believe answering questions that should be closed is something limited to users with <3k rep.

Comment: There's the case where the actual problem is resulting from a typo, and then there's the case where the OP was sloppy when writing their question and made a typo this isn't in their actual code, and the problem still exists when the question has been edited.

Comment: @j08691 well that's OK, that can be down and close-voted for not posting the real code that they tested.

Comment: @j08691 if they fix their question subsequently, it might get reopened if it's now worth answering.

Comment: I support this when a) the problem was a simple typo in the OP's code, not a typo in the question itself b) the problem was resolved and acknowledged by the OP as resolved in comments (e.g. *doh! I need another coffee!; I feel silly now!*) c) there were no answers that provided any reasonable contribution to the site. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102903) for an example. That could also have been closed as a dupe to a debug issue. I suppose I contributed there because the OP actually took the time to write a decent question and seemed genuinely dumbstruck as to the problem.

Comment: Subject to my last comment, why not just keep one or two good 'debug issue' Q&As in your holster to be used with the dupe hammer for typos that have been resolved?

Comment: @jeeped That sounds very much like a work-around to the problem, not a solution.

Comment: How can you tell there's a typo without having a full copy of the user's code? How can you be sure that the typo is indeed to blame?

Comment: The only way to be sure is to get a confirmation from the OP. Speaking of which, it's also probably a good idea to try and [get the close description clarified first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo).

Comment: @DeerHunter - Often they do post sufficient code. I have certainly seen questions like "why do I get this syntax error: Incorrect syntax near 'FORM'?" accompanied by code like `SELECT * FORM SomeTable`

Comment: @DeerHunter If there's a typo, and they haven't posted an MCVE, then I'd say tough luck.

Comment: In my view, "typo" is not a sufficient reason to close a question without at least some consensus. Question pollution can be dealt with efficiently by downvotes. As others have pointed out, we have "This question is caused by a problem that can't be reproduced...." for the purpose of dealing with code typos. And, the line between a simple syntax error and a semantic error isn't often clear enough to make a question worthless.  I believe SO's mechanisms, if they must be imperfect, should err on the side of being supportive of n00bz.

Comment: Usually there are gazillions of questions with the same typo. Find one and use the dupehammer.

Comment: If people are so against have a typo-hammer, how about a halfway house, perhaps a gold (or even silver/bronze) badge holder can vote to close-as-typo that causes a "this is a typo" style message to be emblazoned across the question? This should at least assist OP and other close-voters quickly to close it faster.

Comment: @OllieJones "Question pollution can be dealt with efficiently by downvotes." Not really. That isn't working very well. There are too many people willing to answer these questions and up-vote answers.

Comment: "When a question with an obvious typo appears, the proper course of action is to close it." Actually it was my understanding that the typo has to be the *cause of the problem*, specifically.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, of course, that's what I meant. I edited to make sure it's not just a typo anywhere in the question, but rather a typo that causes the problem described in the question. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the word "typo" is too broadly interpreted and is subject to misuse.  A problem caused by a misunderstanding of the syntax isn't a typo, but I've seen them closed as such.  The question in these cases should be edited to actually make the actual problem easier to identify and search, or the question should be closed as a duplicate of a canonical post if one exists.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "the word "typo" is too broadly interpreted" Similar argument can be made for duplicates, yet the site trusts the judgement of gold badge holders enough to allow them to close duplicates with a single binding vote (the so-called "dupe-hammer" feature). "the question should be closed as a duplicate of a canonical post if one exists" This is much easier said than done, because the same error manifests itself in many unrelated ways. By the time you find a canonical answer there will be ten "Ah, look, you are missing a semicolon!" answers, some with multiple upvotes.

Comment: @psubsee2003 What close reason would you choose in that case?

Comment: @Lamak The newly added one - "caused by a typo", which should be split from the "cannot reproduce", and possibly expanded to include obvious syntactic issues, such as missing/misplaced semicolons, assignments `=` instead of comparisons `==`, and other similar issues.

Comment: The "typo" or "not reproducible" close reasons are tied together under the "this problem was solved in a way that will not help future visitors" banner.  "I forgot a semicolon" is about as helpful to future visitors as "the problem was in another totally unrelated section of my application" or "I had a corrupted config file".  Typos just happen to be the most common type of question closed under this reason.

Comment: Your typo is some noob's "I've been messing with this for hours and it's not getting better". If it's an obvious typo, *answer* them telling them the obvious typo, before closing or voting to close.

Comment: @CharlieMartin Why should we treat noobs who forgot a semicolon any differently than experienced programmer?  Vote to close a typo and leave a comment pointing out the typo.  We don't need garbage questions like this cluttering the site.  Answering the question just makes it extremely likely that the question  will not get deleted automatically by the Roomba.

Comment: Because they're not experienced programmers.

Comment: A nice canonical post, "What is typo and how can I avoid it?" (use an IDE), could solve the problem just like the NullPointer canonical (seems same issue). Probably a gold hammer could just pass a comment where the typo is and then hammer it... Everyone happy, also the OP.

Comment: only problem is that maybe the roomba rules need to be changed to included downvoted questions closed as duplicate... but why not...

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't understood your reference to `Moljrin`, could you explain it please?

Comment: @CharlieMartin So?  SO isn't here to handhold noobs.  A question that has no value to future visitors doesn't suddenly become useful or valuable just because a noob answered it.  We're not even supposed to know they're noobs in the first place ("hello, I started learning how to program yesterday" is distracting fluff that's *supposed* to be removed from questions).

Comment: @Veve the single duplicate close-vote available to gold tag badge holders is called "dupehammer" or "Mjölnir". The proposal here, the "typo-hammer", should be named "Moljrin", or a typo of the former.

Comment: It's amazing how many people think noobs should be allowed to ask question and don't remember they were once noobs too.

Comment: @CharlieMartin No one is saying noobs can't answer questions.  We just expect noobs and veterans to adhere to the same standards.  How many people did this question help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344039/angularjs-ng-controller?  You can find all sorts of similar ["you misspelled X" answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+misspelled) that have no value beyond helping the OP and quick&easy reputation for the answerer.

Comment: [Very closely related question/feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326250/would-it-be-useful-to-have-an-extension-of-mj%C3%B6lnir-close-voting-powers-for-lang).

Comment: @OllieJones *should err on the side of being supportive of n00bz* But this means erring on the side of being **unsupportive** of the experienced users who spend inordinate amounts of time sifting through the chaff, eventually deciding it isn't worth the trouble and they take their marbles and go home. You have to decide if you really want a site which supports the noobies and eventually generates no additional useful information.

Comment: @CharlieMartin Yes, I was once a noobie. Exactly because I was a noobie, I read the documentation. I learned the tools. I figured out how to solve problems. There's nothing wrong with being a noobie. That's not what we're talking about here. We're talking about people (not all of them even noobies) who are lazy, ignorant, and thoughtless.

Comment: And how did you do so? By asking questions and looking for advice from people who are more experienced. You probably also learned that there were people who would call you "lazy, ignorant, and thoughtless" and learned not to bother with them.

I'd far rather the sites not drive people away by acting supercilious and superior.

Answer (score 25):

I would like to propose that questions that were closed under the "solved in a way that will not help future visitors (typos, cannot reproduce, etc.)" reason are eligible to be removed by the Roomba regardless of their status (upvoted, has a selected answer, etc.).  As long as the question is closed in a timely fashion, users who answer such questions will have their reputation gains automatically revoked.

The Roomba already has special rules in place for other closure types (duplicates are not automatically deleted), I can't imagine it would be difficult to add another rule.  I expect this would be easier to implement than a lot of other suggestions like "make gold/silver badge holder votes worth more."

In addition, I would like to see hints added for users who need some training not to answer questions caused by a typo.  If there are votes to close as a typo, add a small warning above the answer form:

> Some users think this question was caused by a typo, do you agree [link to vote box]?  Note that you'll lose any reputation gained by answering this question if it gets closed as a typo.

Comment: Dupes are a built-in *top-level* close reason; typo is a *custom* off-topic reason. Special-casing is therefore rather less handy.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's purely a UI artifact not reflected in the underlying system.

Comment: @Deduplicator Custom reasons can and do vary per site. It's therefore impossible to hard-code proper semantics for them (with the possible exception of the built-in migration sub-sub-menu). Hard-coding semantics for any top-level reason, on the other hand, is much easier, since those are by definition the same on all sites.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is not closing the questions.
The problem is that these questions and their answers get so many up votes that they:

- Show up on the site too much
- Don’t get auto deleted as they have a score of over 0
- Don’t get deleted as few people vote to delete  questions and it needs a lot of delete votes when the question has been up voted.

It seems that most users of Stackoverflow these days don’t have comp sci degrees and consider typos to be of more interest than the type of problem that the “old school” Stackoverflow members care about.

Comment: I don't think that the "modern" SO user values typos more than other types of questions, it's that they're easy to evaluate.  "That dude correctly identified the typo in the question, he deserves an upvote!"  That's not the case with harder questions.

Comment: Considering the demographics of developers [as provided by the most recent survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-education), the whole "old school" argument is a bit harsh and misplaced.  It's not that I don't disagree, it's just that I don't think that whether or not one graduated from college has anything to do with whether or not they like typo-centric questions.

Comment: @Makoto, the survey is misleading, as most people that ask a question only ever ask 1 or 2 question.      The more engaged users are the people that answer the surveys.     Also given the rate of grown at any point in time most users are new users.   (When the site first started it was mostly expert programmers that know about it, due to the blogs it was promoted on.)

Answer (score 4):

*(Posted as an answer, as I am expecting a comment thread to result from this.  Depending on the comments I may post this as a question in its own right.)*

Giving gold badge holders the power to close a “typo” with a single closed vote seems far too much of a risk.    But that does not mean we can give badge holder’s close votes more power.

What if a badge holder’s close vote (in their tag) counted the same a 3 normal close votes, so it just needed two other people to confirm it?

Comment: We already trust gold badge holders to recognize duplicates, which, I think, carries more risk. Currently, this risk is mitigated by the power of gold badge holders to reopen questions closed as duplicates with a single binding vote, i.e. dupe-hammer works both ways. I think this would works the same way with typos.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, there is a lot more agreement on what we mean by "duplicates".

Comment: I think that working out a better agreement on typos is a great goal (I updated the question to mention that as a prerequisite of enacting typo-hammer).

Comment: Except for the fact that some are trying to bend the meaning of the typo close reason to include questions that just aren't going to be useful to future visitors, regardless of whether or not it actually has a typo (which is a subjective reason that should instead be handled by downvoting).

Comment: @KevinB No one is twisting the meaning of anything here.  A few years ago I was having trouble debugging a trigger constraint, so I asked in IRC to verify an assumption I had made.  A lot of time was wasted checking to make sure there wasn't a bug in PostgreSQL when the problem was that I forgot to add rules to make the trigger to fire.  The trigger still didn't do what I was expecting (because I hadn't finished debugging it), but that's an example of a problem unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: @cimmanon,  "trigger constraint" is a good google target, and someone else may have forgotten to enable triggers.

Comment: @IanRingrose But my question wasn't about trigger constraints.  I was trying to verify the behavior of transactions.  That's besides the point.  We shouldn't expect to ask "have you tried turning it off and on again?" to any given question.  We expect questions to be asked in good faith that they actually did check to make sure that they dotted their Is and crossed their Ts.  When a question comes up like "none of the edits to my stylesheet do anything", we shouldn't have to ask "did you make sure you imported it?"

Comment: *Giving gold badge holders the power to close a “typo” with a single closed vote seems far too much of a risk.* **A risk of what, exactly?** Be specific. In your description of the risk, please describe the type of behavior, on the part of what kinds of people, that constitute what % of the universe,  motivated by what factors, that would have what negative impact on what percentage of what other kind of people, and also why you believe the existing mechanisms to mitigate such risks or reverse their impact would not function properly.

Comment: In addition, you cannot assert the existence of a risk as a reason for not doing something without also considering the risk of not doing it. For instance, introducing a carbon tax might carry the risk of harming the economy, whereas not introducing it might carry the risk of all of us being underwater in 2050. Which points to the fact that risk analysis must also weight short-term risks vs. long-term risks.

Comment: @torazaburo, A think one issue is that closing duplicates quickly stops lots of answers, but by the time it is clear the issue is a “typo”, there is little risk of lots of new answers.

Comment: @IanRingrose If I understand you correctly, this is wrong from my personal experience. Typo questions get answers within a few minutes if not a few dozen seconds.

Comment: @torazaburo, but most of the time, we don't know it is **just** a Typo until the "asker" comments on one of the answers to say it worked.

Comment: I'm sort of curious what kind of experience you have with typo questions. I would say we know 99% of the time. To take just one example, consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873409/react-uncaught-syntaxerror#comment63203026_37873409).

Answer (score 4):

There are a few cases of "interesting" typos ([Are typos always off-topic as Q&A?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356342/are-typos-always-off-topic-as-qa)), but most of them of course have an existing answer somewhere on the site.

You could workaround some cases with some well-crafted canonical or existing duplicates, then use your hammer, noone will accuse you of abusing it.

For other ones (call them "useless" / "no replay value") where OP calls variable `a` then `b` and expects it to be the same, yes, gold badge owner is wise enough to assess the technical subject (user got 1000+ votes on 200+ questions), so he/she could decide to close the question single-handedly to avoid useless answers to pour in (like we see a lot at SOCVR in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, but there are a lot in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag as well, like most of popular/widely used languages)

It's completely different than "too broad" or "unclear", which is subject to interpretation. Even moderators rarely use they all-purpose hammer for those cases.

The only restriction I'd set is **the obligation to comment when closing** (since there's no actual target like with the duplicates, but OP has already that all worked out, so I'm paraphrasing), a bit like when issuing a custom close reason. So everyone can see *why* the question was closed as a typo, and if they don't agree, they can comment/ping the user who closed, and other gold badge owners can reopen.

The dupehammer feature isn't abused 99% of the time. Why would that feature be?

That would partially solve a lot of "not enough power" (justified) complaints on that site. 2 at random:

- [Quick delete for obvious unsalvageable questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364990/quick-delete-for-obvious-unsalvageable-questions)
- [Raise the limits on down/close votes at weekends, (and especially Sundays)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365082/raise-the-limits-on-down-close-votes-at-weekends-and-especially-sundays)

Comment: I would be happy to leave a comment in exchange for a hammer-style closure.

Comment: I always do that, even when I close for duplicates (well, unless it's _exactly_ the same) I wanted to post the same exact question, but I found yours first, and it's extremely well documented. Let's hope it's implemented one day (in 6 or 8 weeks, generally speaking)

Answer (score 1):

> We need to work out a better definition of what we collectively consider a typo

Indeed. But the question should be restated without using the word "typo". The real issue is that there are classes of questions, normally of the "it doesn't work" variety, where the problem is **simple**, and unless we think SO is a helpdesk, then these are the ones we want to close. We first need to delineate what "simple" means. A reasonable definition might be

> A simple problem is one that can be solved simply, by reading and understanding basic documentation, searching for answers using readily-available tools such as Google, or using well-known approaches such as re-reading code, viewing error logs, using checking tools, or basic debugging tools.

Leaving aside non-reproducibility for the moment, the phrasing in the current close reason is "simple typographical error". With all due respect to those who have labored mightily over such wording, this is not very clear. Wikipedia says, for example, that typographical errors do not even include misspellings, which it calls an "error of ignorance" (hmm, that seems like a useful term). So in some highly technical sense the current close reason does not even cover a misspelled variable name.

But still, what is the actual criteria based on which we deem a question "simple"? The current wording of the close reason provides a eminently reasonable guideline:

> resolved in a **manner unlikely to help future readers**.

However, as the reason is currently formulated, this is not a **condition** for the close reason to apply; it's an **explanation** of why "typos" is a close reason. We should reverse this: it is not typos that can be closed, because they won't help future readers; rather, it's problems that won't help future readers that can be closed, and typos is one **example** of that.

Therefore, the close reason, assuming we want to keep just one, might read something like:

> This question was caused by a simple problem the resolution of which is unlikely to help future readers. Examples of such simple problems are typos, misspellings, simple syntax errors which could be detected by viewing error output, and simple logical problems that could be detected by using basic debugging techniques.

This reason could include a link to a page talking in more details about such "simple" problems, just as the debugging reason links to a page about MCVE.

Comment: Exactly how is this different from "too localized"? And thus, how will it not cause the exact same problems that "too localized" did?

Comment: I like this better than the current typo, although I would not include simple logical problems that could be detected by using basic debugging techniques, because this arguably includes all logical problems in the world. Since different programmers tend to make identical logical errors, answers to questions that solve such problems may become very helpful, especially when they have a nice description.

Comment: I think you're misreading Wikipedia's exclusion of spelling errors: it's talking about an error where someone writes "acshun" instead of "action" because they actually think that's how it's spelled. Accidental transpositions of letters are covered: "errors due to [...] slips of the hand or finger", so "it won't compile because you wrote `whilee`/`num_cutsomers`/`Dictoinary` on line 10" counts.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't claim to know the history of too-localized. Am I oversimplifying to say it was a good reason (perhaps with a strange name) that was eliminated because it applied to too many questions--which is what we (or at least I) want?

Comment: @torazaburo: A more accurate description would be that it was being used on questions that were not in fact "too localized". It was being used as a catch-all "I don't want this on the site" reason. If you want to read the history of it, just do some searching on Meta.

Comment: (Note, the removal of "Too Localized" was before the MSE/MSO split, so the posts about the change are largely [over there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns).)

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Also, some people were taking "too localized" to mean "no one uses this tech anymore" or "only applicable to certain geographical regions".