# Raise the limits on down/close votes at weekends, (and especially Sundays)

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, vote-to-close, rate-limiting, homework

The weekend homework dumps are becoming unmanageable.  User-moderators are running out of their vote allocation much too early.  I've run out of dv/cv with 5 hours still to go.

I can manage OK with the current allocation of delete votes - they are only really useful on the few really bad questions with an upvoted answer, but the limits on dv/cv were too low before, and are now much too low.

Feature request: relax the weekend limits so as to allow effective moderation throughout the homework-dump-bump.

Comment: Adding to this, perhaps cv is based upon number of questions posted the day before or something like that.

Comment: *I've run out of dv/cv with 5 hours still to go.* ... awesome! Get some fresh-air, you know, outside ... meet real people ... go hiking ...

Comment: @rene Hey! Bailey and I have walked 6km today.   Its doesn't take all that long to eat up those votes on a Sunday:(   Maybe our dog could open an account..

Comment: If your dog has passed the minimal age limit, and it can gain enough rep to close-vote, then go ahead!

Comment: why not allowing to cumulate close votes on a week? ending sunday. Or give 7 times the amount of close votes starting sunday, for the whole week?

Comment: and for the delete votes, _get more rep_, you'll get more delvotes :)

Comment: How about doubling your voting power?  Erm, but wait.  Question volume is 50% of a normal work day but you don't get 50% less close-votes.  So your votes already have twice as much impact.  Nobody should subject themselves to so much misery, time to call it a day.

Comment: @HansPassant the 50% figure is doubtless correct but user-moderators tend to run out of votes more quickly on Sundays.  I assume that this happens because the ratio of good/bad questions is less than 50% of that on a normal weekday:(

Comment: On MSE: [Let me choose when I use my close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166217) @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: I'd argue that users who run out of daily close votes should be able to cast recommend closure flags. If I were a user who would run into this issue, I'd use an alternate account to cast RC flags once I run out of close votes.

Comment: @JoshCaswell exactly!!

Comment: @MartinJames On the figures, it would be nice to gather evidence about them, but I'm rather unsure about which, if any, pieces of data from SEDE are of any use. As a very crude measure, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/830673) suggests the Sunday-to-Monday ratio w.r.t the creation date of closed questions is ~62%, while [for all questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/830674) the corresponding ratio is ~55%. The data may be skewed by, among other things, deleted questions not being included.

Comment: @duplode another possible skew factor is that maybe less of good questions are asked on weekends

Comment: Perhaps base the cap for weekends on other factors such as comments, edits to question/answer etc. which might add value to a simple close vote thus enhance the real goal of better quality content.

Comment: I understand the need, but I don't like the idea of "special days".

Comment: I don't think it needs to be "special days" either (and that opens a cultural can of worms too). Just raise the limits altogether. "You can't handle more than 20 close votes during your day" or w/e is just patronising. I'll be the judge ta!

Comment: These are homework posts?  I thought they were freelance questions raised by people who have promised to duplicate Googles infrastructure using Notepad (apparently that was someones test on a freelance site to see if they read the job spec - he got lots of offers to do the work).

Comment: It seems an XY Problem. We have a lot of bad questions on Sundays so let us raise the CV limits. Perhaps we should focus on how to block or reduce these bad questions

Comment: @gnat Yup, that's possible too. A factor of a different kind to consider would be how large the pool of close voters on weekends is (however we might go about measuring that).

Comment: @Steve That's way harder to implement and would at least take a while, if we even can come up with a good system for that to begin with. The FR in OP on the other hand could be implemented as a first response immediately.

Comment: @BaummitAugen don't read me wrong. I have complained a lot about the _deluge of late "sunday night" questions with "life or death" timeline_ and, if it is feasible to raise the limits, I would appreciate. But the problem is still the same: We are trying to empty the boat with a spoon.

Comment: @Steve Agreed, I did not want to say we should do one or the other; if we can come up with some way to reduce the load of poor questions, I certainly won't complain.

Comment: 'if we can come up with some way to reduce the load of poor questions' oh, sure! Yes!  Unfortunately, nobody has been able to come up with an acceptable solution after many years of trash tsunamis:(

Comment: follow-up / complementary request for data: [Stats to compare efficiency of close votes cast on weekends vs weekdays](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365136/839601)

Comment: When you say the weekend, how would you deal with different time zones?

Comment: @Chris_Rands probably by looking at the traffic logs; the 'weekend' probably would cover 5PM on Friday GMT - 5 or so (for the US where SO is physically located and the majority of traffic comes from) to about 5AM Monday. Or to make it simple: midnight GMT to midnight GMT for a 48 hour period.

Comment: Makes sense.  [It's pretty clear that weekends have a lot more traffic](https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc#/trafficCard) and that certain type of newbie questions spike on weekends.

Comment: Definition of a "weekend" as days one is not expected to work vary around the world, not Saturday/Sunday everywhere. Should aim for a solution that affords the same privileges to all users.

Comment: it is wednesday but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541373/cant-create-main-o-no-such-directory-or-file

Comment: `Please do this `

Comment: Also, I have to include my plug for my [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) to reduce the number of votes required to close questions to 3 or 4.

Comment: what does sunday have to do with a daily vote limit? Nada.

Answer (score 14):

Anecdotally, you are but one person close and downvoting poor* questions.  Anecdotally, *one* person cannot hope to weather the storm of poor questions on their own.  So one would hope that there are *others* which are helping you out here.

That said, I remain unconvinced that this is an actual necessary feature unless we can see demonstrated numbers that poor* questions are tough to moderate on the weekend.  From what I know, the overall site participation numbers fall off a cliff between Friday and Saturday UTC, and the downvoting doesn't change all *that* much during that period of time.

The onus here is on you to prove that these questions are proving to be too much for us to handle during the quieter hours of site activity.  I'm not seeing it, since all you have is anecdotal evidence.

<sup>*: Hopefully you're not nuking good homework questions *just* because they're homework questions...</sup>

Comment: well FWIW I checked my close voting history for few last weeks and there seem to be "spikes" of non-closed questions on weekends (March 3-4, 10-11 and 17-18) compared to weekdays. Including such blatant cases as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49087059/839601) (close votes expired, gimme a f#cking break)

Comment: @gnat:  Is that more closely correlated with the fact that there's simply less traffic on those days?

Comment: hard to tell. One thing I know for sure is I close-vote same kind questions on weekends as on weekdays, and what I see is that weekend questions seem to stay open much more frequently. It looks like on weekends my votes just have less effect

Comment: ...oh by the way, this kind of hints on what kind statistics we can look for in order to learn whether the issue is real or imaginary. Pick a bunch of active close voters and compare efficiency of their votes on weekdays vs weekends, what percentage of their votes ends with questions getting closed, deleted, unanswered

Comment: If I had directed my post more widely, then I would been accused of putting words in others' mouths when I have no right to speak for them.  So, this is what I have fouind.  There are voting buttons for those who agree/disagree.

Comment: @gnat: dear god, that Russian one has been up for 3 weeks. I've cast Close Vote #4; *please* have someone put it down now.

Comment: @MartinJames:  I kinda want to see a bit more backbone from you on this.  You stand a very good chance to convince me here, since there's the smell of more than anecdotal evidence.  You just have to take that next step and *prove* that this needs to be done.

Comment: @gnat So the way you've phrased it indicates to me not that there are more questions that need closing on weekends, just that there are fewer people casting close votes on the weekends. So giving people more close votes wouldn't do anything to fix *that* problem.

Comment: @TylerH you're right about that I think primary issue is there are fewer people. Giving more close votes could in theory solve that (think of 5 active users using 1000 votes each to close 1000 questions, stuff like that) but without stats ([requested here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365136/839601])) it seems somewhat pointless to drill deeper...

Comment: ...another potentially concerning thing is, what if homework cheaters already learned about that it's easier to get through on weekends. If this becomes (became?) a widely known trick then we may easily get more questions that need closing. "Hey fellow classmates! if you want your h/w dump to get better chances for help, just post in on weekend. Share this wisdom on Twitter, Facebook and everywhere else, help other students"

Answer (score 4):

While discussing [stats request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365136/839601) related to this issue I re-checked explanation of [how items are prioritized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773) in close queue and, you know, if system really works as described there then it actually makes weekend questions *escape completion of close vote review*:

> the more previous reviews a given task has had, the closer to the top of the queue it'll be... preference is also given to the most recently queued items...

Let's see, imagine a close-worthy question asked on weekend. Someone's vote / flag pushes it in close queue where it hangs unattended because there are less reviewers on weekend. Okay, now new week starts and active reviewers get back to the queue... but!

But at this moment our question is heavily lower in priority by both of the stated criteria: first, because it has too few reviews (since there were too few reviewers to look at it on weekend) and second, because it has been queued too long ago (a day or two before, at this age it just can't compete with questions that entered queue in last few hours).

As a result it gets to the very bottom of the queue with zero chances for reviewers to check it, eventually [ages away from it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/839601) and hangs open, probably misleading inexperienced askers into belief that such questions are okay.

---

I think it would be interesting to see what happens if close queue prioritization was somehow tweaked to account for above. Most straightforward approach would probably be to simply ignore weekend hours when calculating "queuing age" parameter.

This kind of things looks easy to measure: just calculate percentage of questions that age away from queue for those that enter it on weekends and weekdays. If prioritization is done right there shouldn't be big difference.

Answer (score -58):

> The weekend homework dumps are becoming unmanageable.

Really, I haven't noticed a problem, so you must be wrong. I'm curious what you mean by "unmanageable". What is your role in the Stack Overflow hierarchy that you are "managing" all the questions that come in on the weekend?

Snark aside, this site is not about users getting a high score or maxing out their vote uses each day, but rather the opposite: these votes of yours are a limited feature to allow you to help out just a bit. If there is a deluge of problematic posts on a given time, more than "users" can handle, then we should have an election to increase the number of moderators. Luckily, that is what we are having *as I type*.

It is not the *job* of users to act as janitors or bouncers to the site. If you find yourself frustrated by the quality of questions, do what you can to improve them or remove them; the site grants you extensive tools as a user to do that. If you have exhausted your tools, then just move to a different tag, or go outside, or play a video game. You are (hopefully) not being forced to look at the questions page for any specific length of time.

Comment: *Really, I haven't noticed a problem, so you must be wrong.* Does that extend to all of Stack Overflow? When you don't notice something it's simply not there?

Comment: This is a strange answer. While I get the concerns about e.g. unlimited close voting, the argument here reads like conformity for the sake of conformity. "It is not the **job** of users to act as janitors or bouncers to the site" -- loaded words aside, the fact is the site relies on its users for content curation.

Comment: @Adriaan It's snark to emphasize how the request is framed in such an opinionated and odd way.

Comment: @duplode I am all for more close votes and more delete votes. But not because Martin James doesn't like homework questions or thinks weekends on SO suck. This is a direct response to how problematically he framed the request.

Comment: Being opinionated here isn't problematic -- this is Meta, after all. If the underlying issue here is the lack of non-anecdotal evidence in Martin's post, I can kind of see where you are coming from. However (1) your answer, for all of its intensity, doesn't address that directly; (2) I consider it problematic to shut down Meta discussions due to the OP not providing non-anecdotal evidence in cases in which it is not at all obvious how to gather such evidence.

Comment: @duplode It depends on what subject the opinion is held on. Asking for a system change based on an opinion not backed up by even unsourced numbers is not a laudable use of opinion even on Meta. Some things are not really appropriate "opinion" subjects. And this isn't shutting down Meta discussion, it is participating in it. If I wanted to shut down the discussion I would vote to close the question.

Comment: "If I wanted to shut down the discussion I would vote to close the question" -- That's fair. I do think, though that it's not a big step from this stance to finding a "can no longer be reproduced" vote on such questions appropriate. On this broader point, I feel [the discussion here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336622/can-we-talk-about-the-reviewing-culture-here-on-meta#comment406122_336623), though originated in a rather different context, is somewhat relevant.

Comment: 'What is your role in the Stack Overflow hierarchy that you are "managing" all the questions that come in on the weekend?' - I can't win.  If I phrased it more widely, some user would complain 'Hey - you don't speak for us!'.  So, I refer only to my own experiences and, if others wish to (dis)agree, they can downvote/upvote.

Comment: @duplode I suppose folks could make that step, but I would frown upon people using that close reason on this question so long as users have the vote-to-close privilege. It's more appropriate for site features which are no longer part of the site, like SO Documentation (or for bug reports which are already fixed).

Comment: @MartinJames FYI I don't take any issue with you or with the desire for more CVs/Del-Vs; I hope you don't take the criticism personally in my answer. I sympathize with you as a fellow SOCVR regular especially. I just can't support this request as it is currently reasoned.

Comment: I support this answer. The question reads like _"I like shoveling crap, gimme a bigger shovel!"_, ignoring the underlying cause.

Comment: @CodeCaster: that simile of yours made me re-think the question, the issue it attempts to solve (and how), and this answer. Well done.