# Increase the number of votes required to close a question to 6

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Currently, it takes **5** close votes to reach the closing threshold. Each person with >=**3000** reputation can cast **50** close votes per day.

Problems:

1. It's not difficult to reach 3000 reputation. One way to get that is getting 600 up-votes. This is a number reachable on one question. Getting up-votes on one question doesn't mean the person has good judgement (about whether a question is good and in-topic), or even benevolent. So the quality of close voters are not guaranteed.
2. The closing committee is too small. If you can't guarantee the quality of a group of people in charge of power, you should increase the number of positions so that the many good are not managed by a few bad. Unfortunately the current threshold `n = 5` is far too small. If the probability of making a wrong judgement is `p`, then the probability of a question being wrongfully closed by the first `n` comrades is `p^n`. The error rate decreases exponentially with the threshold. So increasing the threshold is exponentially helpful.
3. Some people like following others. Some people are easily influenced by others. If they see there are already 2 close votes on a question, they don't hesitate casting the 3rd. This makes it even easier to reach the threshold. Yes I haven't included closing trolls and closing managers who simply enjoy abusing their power.
4. A person can cast 50 close votes per day? This is the very number that needs to be reduced, not the closing threshold. This number is basically saying how many bullets you can carry with your gun. Plus the fact that your gun automatically reloads the next day. No need to elaborate on the consequences I think.
5. [Presumption of innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence) is a legal right in many countries and international human right under the UN's [Universal Declaration of Human Rights](http://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/), Article 11. If a question is controversial, it should be kept open. It's far more harmful to prevail censorship and hinder freedom of speech than to keep some garbage on server which you can choose not to see. See next.
6. The forum has a search function, which minimize the negative effects of garbage questions. If garbage questions don't show up in search results, they don't harm users. If they do, improve the search algorithm. The Internet also has a lot of garbage. You can't close them all, but you know how to use search engines.
7. If you feel garbage questions are wasting storage and bandwidth resources, you can do automatic garbage collection. You can set a lifetime to each question and recycle it if it doesn't receive a given threshold of popularity. This automatically balances the server load over time without human intervention. Moreover, it gives each question a time to survive before it's killed prematurely.
8. If you are interested, there's [an opposite question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) which asks to reduce the number of votes required to close a question.

Statistics:

- 12 downvotes from the first 21 views.
- 4 close votes (off-topic) within 30 minutes.
- Put on hold (off-topic) within 35 minutes.

Edits:

- Re-titled from **Increase the number of votes required to close a question** to **Increase the number of votes required to close a question to 6**, which looks more consistent with [**Reduce the number of votes required to close a question to 4**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4), which is certainly not off-topic.

Comment: Like we can close we can also reopen .. so if you don't agree, reopen and maybe *Some people will like following you*

Comment: No, disagree.  We need more effective moderation, not less, to cope with the large number of bad questions.  Addng extra work to those curators that already exist will do more harm than good.  It's trivially easy to use up the entire close vote allocation on a Sunday alone  We need to encourage more users to curate effectively, (for example: some users have issued 160 times more upvotes than downvotes, and that can't be good for site quality).

Comment: I find that a lot of your points contradict each other. One of them  being your first ones, "it's easy to get 3k rep" and then you go on saying there's too few who can close questions

Comment: 'Yes I haven't included closing trolls and closing managers who simply enjoy abusing their power' this again.  Do you have any evidence that such users exist, (no)?  Deserves a rude/abusive flag on its own, but meta, so I'll let it go:(

Comment: @MartinJames So what makes you think bad questions must be **closed** instead of **not showing up in search results**? The judgement about whether a question is good or bad can be fairly subjective. Others may need what you don't want so you don't have to destroy it. This is freedom.

Comment: 'Prsumption of innocence' etc.... obviously, you consider that only applies to Q/A posters, and not close-voters, whom you judge as guilty of abuse of power without any evidence.   More internal inconsistency, as already noted by @Epodax :(

Comment: @Epodax First one is about how much effort you need to get that position. Second one is about how many positions are available. Think it. Think it again.

Comment: We close content which isn't on topic to give the OP a chance to edit it into shape.  We delete actively bad and harmful content. Make the most of your time and edit your specific question instead of fussing about concepts like "freedom" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Cyker I can't close questions on my own.  I don't even have any gold dupehammers.  I can apply one close vote.  Four others have to agree, as you know.

Comment: There's no limit on how many who can reach 3k rep and by that extend no limit to how many who can get the close vote privilege.

Comment: @Epodax But it only ever needs 5 **for a specific question**.

Comment: *A person can cast 50 close votes per day?* - no... it's **40**...

Comment: @JonClements Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Do you need a screenshot?

Comment: As for you point (4), I have already addressed the 40/50 limit in another meta Q: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365082/758133

Comment: @Cyker I take that back - a bit of a brain burp - it's 40 close *reviews* a day - not *votes*.... So yeah - it's **50**... my bad.

Comment: Your arguments are making little sense to me and I honestly don't see the point of this, this is nothing but a rant.

Comment: @Epodax Evidence, please...

Comment: @JonClements It doesn't matter. The number is public.

Comment: ... Evidence of what?

Comment: @Epodax *I find that a lot of your points contradict each other.* and *this is nothing but a rant.*

Comment: @Cyker I was going to ask you for evidence regarding why this is a problem that needs to be addressed via mechanisms that don't already exist. Off-topic questions get closed, if they happen to get closed incorrectly, they can be re-opened... Not everyone uses anywhere near 50 close votes a day (most just a couple as they browse the site in their favourite tags and some never use them at all). What exactly is the issue you wish to address? **What** is the problem?

Comment: I already pointed out some of the points that I find to contradict each other, as for the rant that's more of a personal opinion. But then is the contradiction part so it's really gonna be hard to find any "evidence"

Comment: @Cyker Another nice statistic: 7800 questions currently awaiting close vote review because it requires so many votes. Many of them eventually expire. Increasing the amount needed will increase that problem.

Comment: @JonClements *Once a question has been closed, it will no longer accept new answers*. So the author *cannot receive any help* from peers until a group of people with enough privilege reopen it. If people ask questions on this site, it's likely they need answers for the work at hand, right now.

Comment: @Epodax At least you now admit that you are *opinion-based* :) For the contradiction part, think it a 3rd time. Drawing a bar graph may also help.

Comment: I'm out, I'd recommend taking a break and cool down a little

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I understand there are a lot of garbage on this site and moderators are probably having a high workload. But as I said there is **SEARCH**. Why the garbage must be closed instead of not showing up in search results?

Comment: @Epodax I'm cool as always dude ;)

Comment: @Cyker There's no guarantees how quickly you'll get an answer (if at all here). If you're in a rush to get something answered, that's of no concern to the volunteers on this site. It's up to the OP to ask a question that is on-topic to start with - if you ask an off-topic question and it gets closed then that's down to the OP - no one else. If you really want an answer - ask a decent on-topic question to start with. If a question is closed, the OP can edit it to make it on-topic, then it goes in a review queue and if it's now okay, quickly gets reopened... So again... the mechanisms are there.

Comment: The only thing that has merit in this question is *The closing committee is too small* if it had considered the total number of users that take a seat in any closing committee. There are more then enough users > 3K rep, still only a handful exercise their privileges on a daily basis. If those that are willing to participate increase, so will the quality of close voting. I'm not sure if this question is seen by the potential of close voters as an invitation for them to take up close voting, giving it the unbiased outcome you seem to be looking for.

Comment: @JonClements My friend, you don't see the **off-topic** thing is interesting: **Increase the number of votes required to close a question** is marked as off-topic, but **Reduce the number of votes required to close a question to 4** is obviously not off-topic (and has received >100 up-votes). Probably an on-topic question should be titled **Increase the number of votes required to close a question to 6**.

Comment: @Cyker One reason is that your post is essentially a feature request, but tagged as discussion. The close reason indicates that it is closed because it does not invite participation or discussion from the community, and it can see why it feels like that. You might want to officially tag it feature request. And please stop using the bold formatting so much, it just generates dislike

Comment: "*If you feel garbage questions are wasting storage and bandwidth resources, you can do automatic garbage collection.*" I agree. We need *more aggressive* [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: @Yvette - the question has the [discussion] tag.  Comments *are* meant for extended discussion at meta, there is no other way to have one.  We went over this before, what is it that you try to accomplish?

Comment: "It's far more harmful to prevail censorship and hinder freedom of speech " [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1357/)

Comment: I think it's also fair to say, about the off-topicness, that EJoshuaS' question sounds like a "I think this would help for the following reasons". Your request feels closer to "I have decided this is the change Stack needs. Don't ask me why, it's self-evident. And if you disagree, you're wrong". One invites more discussion than the other. Not saying I necessarily agree with the closure, but it's definitely relevant to point out

Comment: @Patrice Simply the opposite. I meant for a discussion to hear how other people think about it and that's why I tagged it with `discussion` from Revision 1. But someone insisted on it being a feature request and added the `feature-request` tag for me. This is a good example of showing how moderators can be subjective. Good if one doesn't twist facts and impose his/her own ideas on other people. Check revisions.

Comment: I've seen this question since you created it, so I've seen all revisions, thanks. Even as a discussion, your post sounds a lot like "this is the truth, just don't try to argue anything about it. I'm right, period". Which makes it feel like you're not very open to discussion. Whether that's true or not is debatable, but I'd say the way you respond in comments definitely continues giving that vibe :/... And the accusations about freedom of speech, the attacks on other curators of the site, etc etc... makes it a lot more "ranty" than it has to be... which detracts from your arguments.

Comment: @patrice Looking back at history, I didn't say anything is *truth*, or performed any *attacks*, and every time *rant* appeared was neither in my questions nor in my comments. Human beings are not only subjective but also imaginative?

Comment: Sure. I am trying to help you see this from the point of view of others. Apologies for trying to help I guess. Have a good day

Comment: @Patrice Well, it's good to understand the point of view of others. But it's confusing to understand how that point of view is formed. Have a good day

Comment: You want to see how the PoV was formed? " Yes I haven't included closing trolls and closing managers who simply enjoy abusing their power.", and "No need to elaborate on the consequences" makes it feel like (for the first one) you have an axe to grind against some curators, and (the second one) that you think your argument doesn't need explaining.  Hopefully this makes it clearer. I don't think the stance you post the question under invites anyone to discuss it with you, and I think the way you answer every comment is doing this even more.

Comment: @Patrice That axe scene is vivid. However, my attitude towards bad people are to let them go through a trial, not to use violence on them. This also explains why I don't want to elaborate on violent scenes. It helps people stay comfortable, especially those who have experienced such a scene themselves.

Comment: This is an expression, if you aren't familiar with it https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158346/origin-of-to-have-an-axe-to-grind  Nothing violent or vivid about it....

Comment: @Patrice Not many people have fought an axe man and they won't understand what you think of when you see that word.

Comment: Can we get back to the topic at hand, not the intricacies of the English language's expressions? You asked for why I formed my PoV, I delivered. No need to discuss about what you think of this English expression.

Comment: @Patrice Topic at hand is moderators think closing votes are very useful despite of possible negative effects on newbies. And obviously they don't plan to drop or weaken them. So your PoV probably doesn't work here. Sad.

Comment: Topic at hand was you asking me to explain why your post can be seen as a rant. I explained that, then instead of trying to understand that PoV you picked one thing about my argument (the expression I chose) and decided to go and discuss that. Again, this makes you feel very unreceptive to discussion or feedback. Anyway, if you can't see why by now, I have better things to do.

Comment: @Patrice Well this is a good PoV learning experience but if you have better things to do you are always free to go. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 15):

Since this is essentially a feature request, I'll address it like a feature request:

> It's not difficult to reach 3000 reputation. One way to get that is
>   getting 600 up-votes. This is a number reachable on one question.
>   Getting up-votes on one question doesn't mean the person has good
>   judgement (about whether a question is good and in-topic), or even
>   benevolent. So the quality of close voters are not guaranteed.

1. There's a reputation cap of 200 a day, so these 600 question upvotes (would be only 300 answer upvotes) would have to be spread perfectly evenly across 15 days. That is highly unlikely as highly voted posts usually recieve their votes in large bursts.
2. There have been [only 4](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a600) posts with a cumulative score of 600 or higher created this year. Only **one** user gained close vote privileges from their post, and even that user only gained 772 reputation from his 2234(!) scoring post due to the rep cap.

> The closing committee is too small. If you can't guarantee the quality
>   of a group of people in charge of power, you should increase the
>   number of positions so that the many good are not managed by a few
>   bad. Unfortunately the current threshold n = 5 is far too small. If
>   the probability of making a wrong judgement is p, then the probability
>   of a question being wrongfully closed by the first n comrades is p^n.
>   The error rate decreases exponentially with the threshold. So
>   increasing the threshold is exponentially helpful.

This point is why we have a reopen process, complete with review queue to get it in front of the right eyes. Increasing the threshold is not "exponentially helpful" when looked at from a "garbage that should be closed stays around instead" perspective. For that, it is exponentially harmful.

> Some people like following others. Some people are easily influenced
>   by others. If they see there are already 2 close votes on a question,
>   they don't hesitate casting the 3rd. This makes it even easier to
>   reach the threshold. Yes I haven't included closing trolls and closing
>   managers who simply enjoy abusing their power.

The same goes for upvotes and reopen votes, so I think that balances out. I'll ignore the rude and insulting jab at curators for the sake of your argument here.

> A person can cast 50 close votes per day? This is the very number that
>   needs to be reduced, not the closing threshold. This number is
>   basically saying how many bullets you can carry with your gun. Plus
>   the fact that your gun automatically reloads the next day. No need to
>   elaborate on the consequences I think.

I'm confused. Do you or do you not propose to raise the threshold? And yes, you do need to elaborate on the consequences. Closing questions isn't akin to bullets in a gun, it's akin to taking a broom to the parking lot in hopes of making it less of a mess when the next person tries to find a parking spot.

> Presumption of innocence is a legal right in many countries and
>   international human right under the UN's Universal Declaration of
>   Human Rights, Article 11. If a question is controversial, it should be
>   kept open. It's far more harmful to prevail censorship and hinder
>   freedom of speech than to keep some garbage on server which you can
>   choose not to see. See next.

This is a private website and not a court. This site reserves the right to remove you or your posts at any point where convenient. Posts being closed and deleted is not a suppression of free speech, since stack exchange is not part of the government. Your freedom to express unvaluable content does not trump the site's interest in maintaining its quality.

> The forum has a search function, which minimize the negative effects
>   of garbage questions. If garbage questions don't show up in search
>   results, they don't harm users. If they do, improve the search
>   algorithm. The Internet also has a lot of garbage. You can't close
>   them all, but you know how to use search engines.

The vast majority of SO traffic comes from google indexing. There is no builtin way to stop a post from being indexed, so yes, garbage questions staying around does clutter search results for no reason.

It sounds like you want bad questions to stay around, but be completly undiscoverable by searching. What's the difference to now where they're deleted then except that red backline color that tells you it's deleted?

> If you feel garbage questions are wasting storage and bandwidth
>   resources, you can do automatic garbage collection. You can set a
>   lifetime to each question and recycle it if it doesn't receive a given
>   threshold of popularity. This automatically balances the server load
>   over time without human intervention. Moreover, it gives each question
>   a time to survive before it's killed prematurely.

See previous, storage space is not a consideration here, as even deleted posts are still kept on file in case they get undeleted.

All in all I think this is a bad idea for the reasons outlined above. I think increasing the CV threshold would only serve to further back up the review queue and leave more bad questions unclosed.

Comment: I would just like to point out: From the birth of this question, I meant for a **discussion**, not requesting anything. That's why I tagged my question with `discussion` since **Revision 1**. It's **you**, as a **moderator**, calling this a **feature-request** and added the `feature-request` tag in **Revision 9**. This is a good example of showing how people can be subjective so that being over-strict on closing questions, and in general, acting on behalf of others, is a bad idea.

Comment: @Cyker This is clearly a feature-request, the original title even was *"Increase the number of votes required to close a question"*, perhaps you should have titled it *"**Should we** Increase the number of votes required to close a question"*. If you feel so strongly about it, you're well within your right to remove the tag. (As you can see, the other question that you linked referring to reducing the requirement was a feature-request, which you even changed your questions title to be in line with)

Comment: @NickA *Increase the number of votes required to close a question* simply describes something people may do. It doesn't mean I'm requesting anyone to do it. Isn't it clear through a `discussion` tag that this question is about hearing opinions to help understand pros and cons? Do we really have to make every discussion question title longer by forcing authors to use a format like *DISCUSSION: Increase the number of votes required to close a question*?

Comment: @Cyker No but you should at least provide a prompt for discussion, you've given a list of *"problems"* and a title of *"Increase the number of votes required to close a question to 6"* with the tag `discussion`... Ok, discuss what? What do you want us to say? Have you got any specific questions? Any reason why these problems are a problem? Why you think this would help with those problems?

Comment: @NickA Discuss, for example, whether the site would have experienced other problems if the threshold is increased.

Comment: @Cyker yes!  Curators would waste even more volunteer effort on closing sub-prime questions and so spend less on handling good questions.  That's another problem.