# Separate reasons for "typo" or "cannot reproduce"

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I never understood why "typo" and "cannot reproduce" were the same close reason.

- typo: there can be interesting typos, or stupid ones. But at least we can answer/comment/close as duplicate because it's trivial to reproduce and fix
- cannot reproduce: OP needs to create a [mcve], or has a bad tool install, broken paths, using an old version of a tool without tagging properly his/her question. Some people *can* reproduce because they're lucky to have the same version of language/tool as OP, some can't (sometimes OP editing allows to retract the flag)

Those are 2 *very* different close reasons (well, to be accurate, "cannot reproduce" is actually "can no longer be reproduced", "no longer" can be "right now", which is potentially because OP fixed the typo in the question rendering the question moot)

Why not 2 separate radioboxes in the "Close" window ?

(after all there are 2 separate radioboxes for "Unclear what you're asking" and "Too broad", and it's sometimes difficult to pick between the two)

This was inspired by [Closing questions with typos faster: typo-hammer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319399/closing-questions-with-typos-faster-typo-hammer), that I'm also backing up. A first step would be to separate the close reasons so gold badge owners can close typo questions, not "cannot reproduce" questions.

Comment: Yeah - I never understood it either.

Comment: The phrasing in the typo close reason was meant to acknowledge that the OP changed his code and no longer has the problem.  Very common, rubber ducky got the job done.

Answer (score 8):

I get that Stack Overflow has a bit of a bikeshed problem, but there are *some* questions out there that really are just too trivial to justify answering anymore.  A typo in a question - even if it is "interesting" (and I've yet to see interesting typos - mostly annoying and intentionally confusing ones like Unicode-oriented typos), and a problem that can't be reproduced, are the types of questions which we just can't realistically answer, lest there be even *more* bikesheds than we have already.

I don't see a reason to separate these two close reasons since it effectively boils down to the same "fix": **ensure that your issue is consistently reproducible and correct as you know it to be.**  Typos aren't "correct" code since someone fat-fingered a zero infront of a digit, making it octal.  Errors that can't be reproduced could be caused by someone running their code on HP-UX instead of x86.  Not much we can say or do in those circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

> Those are 2 very different close reasons.

Yes they are.

> Why not 2 separate radioboxes in the "Close" window ?

There are.  That second problem merits:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

That's the appropriate course of action when the question does not contain enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok, then the close reason "typo" should be left alone. "can no longer reproduced" should be the corner case when OP edited the question to fix the typo, and now the code works...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If anyone (including the OP) edits the question to fix the problem that the question was asking about, then that edit should be rolled back.  That's not an appropriate edit.

Comment: agreed. Rolled back and closed as typo. So the "can no longer be reproduced" bit should be removed. suits me fine as well. Nice thinking out of the box. I think people misinterpreted your answer. The message needs to be changed, though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's there for issues that *the OP* can no longer reproduce, which is different from them simply not including enough information in the question for *others* to reproduce it.  For example, if someone asks, "why is this code failing to connect to this network computer" when the actual problem was "the remote computer was unplugged" or "I actually ran the wrong executable when trying to test it" or something along those lines.

Comment: looks very much like "no [mcve]" then. Are there a lot of those corner cases? A typo isn't like plugging a cord at all.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There certainly is some overlap between pretty much all of the close reasons.  In this case they're separated out based on the appropriate path to take going forward, and the instructions for the author of the question.  In one case they need to construct a working MCVE, in the other they just don't care anymore and there's no saving the question.  After all, you could just use "unclear" for either of them if you just wanted to pick any close reason that technically applied.  We don't do that because it's less helpful to question authors.