# questions about "parsing JSON"

Tags: discussion

Hardly an hour goes by without someone asking a question about how to access a particular piece of data that they got from parsing JSON. The most recent is

[Retrieving JSON and extracting a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518410/retrieving-json-and-extracting-a-specific-value)

It seems like 99% of the time, as in this one, they just didn't notice that part of the object is an array, and they need to index it.

Are these questions really of any value to the community? Every one of them is a one-off, although I suppose if someone read one of them it might give them a clue to the mistake they made in their program. They're all so trivial that it doesn't seem worthwhile posting a real answer -- I'd like to just post the corrected expression as a comment and close it, but what close reason?

Is there a canonical question that explains how to read JSON and turn it into access expressions? Then they could be closed as dupes of that. If there are different ones for various languages, that would be fine, too.

Comment: For the most part, it's not even JSON they're talking about. The example is actually asking, "How do I access something in this JavaScript object graph". Which, when you think about it, is JavaScript programming 101.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - then that qualifies them for **too broad** and a down vote.

Comment: https://s1.postimg.io/7ge8xeulr/flamethrower.jpg

Comment: @Pekka웃 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q

Comment: You could create your own.  Ask a very general question about parsing json, then add an answer that details specific scenarios.  Then close as dupe away.

Comment: I close as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json. "Too broad" seems wrong to me.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson One issue with all these "trivial logic errors" is that they're extremely common. Things like forgetting an index when processing nested structures, `=` instead of `==`, using `||` instead of `&&` when testing for a variable not equal to many things, forgetting parentheses when using `AND` and `OR` together in SQL, etc. So answers *are* likely to help future readers, except that they'll never find the previous questions on their own.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've long ago decided that I'm not interested in tilting at windmills. So I don't bother trying to correct the JSON vs. data terminology, or telling people to switch from mysql to mysqli/PDO, etc. I want to help them with the practical issues in their programming, not get caught up in minutiae.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I wasn't suggesting wading into that swamp, just that it's so basic to JavaScript (and indeed many, many other languages) that I wonder why people seem to have such problems with it, and that perhaps, as you were saying, it should not be entertained on SO.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I wonder why people have such problems with many of the things they ask about. I think the root cause is that many people are trying to program who just don't have the right kind of logical mind for it. They don't understand the general processes, they're just learning everything by rote. How many times have you seen someone say they didn't think they could use some function in a particular context, because they thought it could only be used in some other way.

Comment: I don't know why people think this is related to mental typo, except for the fact that I guess in this particular subcategory of these cases it can be considered a mental typo to omit the array index reference. But there are many questions of this kind which are not about mental typos, but are rather just "how to access the `a` property in the `b` property.

Comment: LINQ question in the c# tag has similar issues.  Users want someone to write a customized query to solve their very specific use case and not try to figure out the query on their own from all of the existing posts on SO and on other sites

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's the common problem of "Write this for me" posts. Just vote to close as "Too broad".

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a canonical question that explains how to read JSON and turn it into access expressions?

- JavaScript: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).
- PHP: [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Thanks, I've bookmarked them for future reference.

Comment: That JS post is a fantastic canonical that I will regularly be using as a dupe target.

Answer (score -7):

## Too Broad

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
> too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
> or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

There are too many ways to process JSON in each language to have a canonical answer that does not turn into a **recommendations** question/answer.

The problem is they are a form or **too localized**. Which does not exist anymore and was superseded in spirit with **too broad** in that *how to parse JSON in what ever language* or *how do I debug* or *how do I pay more attention to what I am doing* is actually the answer.

Maybe we need **too narrow** as a close reason since **too localized** has such a stigma now.

Comment: But the questions are not actually about parsing, they're about basic observation of the data.

Comment: If that is the case then this question is just a duplicate of [Closing as a Mental Typo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo) in spirit if not in practice.

Comment: I disagree that "too localized was superseded in spirit by too broad". They are quite different. Most of these questions should can and should be downvoted, but I don't think they fall cleanly into any of the available close reasons.