# How control to answers on comments?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I'm a pretty new using SO (and contributing) but I read every day, a lot of questions that were answered in comments. And after that, the questions appear with no responses in the search.

How is controlled this (if its controlled)? From my position (part of the community) can I help with any action?

I'm sorry if that is a old discussion, I searched info but didn't find it.

Comment: My unwritten rule is: if I put the solution in the comments, anybody is free to take it and turn it into an answer (if you got the answer from comments, the common courtesy of giving credit is welcome.)

Comment: You could always make it [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) after answering.

Comment: Note that if the question is "a typo, or otherwise not useful to future readers" (I can't remember the close reason exactly) it should be closed as such. [Mental typo also counts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313884/closing-as-a-mental-typo).